# Can I sit under my oak tree or do I need to go on rep hunt?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, post-ban

I'm answering questions on low traffic tags and I have always had a bit of fear of the answer ban. My tactics has been to now and then go on rep hunt in the high traffic tag Java, pass a quick answer, get some quick upvotes, and then return back under my oak tree.

This was ok since I also wanted to reach the 3K mark that I needed to clean up my home turf!

Now I'm there (3K) and I would prefer to stay and "*[smell the flowers](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ferdinand%20smell%20the%20flowers)*".

[image: Under the oak tree]

In low-traffic tags it's not likely to get upvotes, but you manage to get answers accepted (currently I'm around 50%, accepted answer percentage rate). I would like to answer some old question in "my" tag and probably it can drop to 40%, if I do this.

I know that "the **exact** formula for the bans is not disclosed", but could someone give me directions on what to look out for (e.g. "accepted answer percentage rate", "number of answers in sequence not accepted nor voted")?

The question is, how does this apply "[significant **zero-voted** answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)", since answering old question in low-traffic tags easily can generate a "zero-voted" non accepted answer, maybe it is better to not do this or you need to offset with up votes on other question?

Comment: Just wondering what exactly makes you so jumpy about getting an answer ban? Have you ever gotten an indication that you are close to one or something like that?

Comment: I don't think you can get an answer ban if you have only or almost only neutrally scored ones, but no (or close to no) negatively scored ones.

Comment: No but I try to be careful and correct on how I move around on SO, and since I see that there is this feature, answering old low-traffic tags make me worry... (I could easily get 10 answers, 0 score, 0 accepted answers doing this)

Comment: Is there an indication when you get close?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think as long as you don't intentionally post LQ answers and a tons of them you won't get a answer ban

Comment: related: [Is “Sparrows and Owls” a useful model of answering behavior?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263138/is-sparrows-and-owls-a-useful-model-of-answering-behavior)

Comment: But to answer your concern - you are answering questions and getting a good response (I don't see many negatively scored ones). You are very far from getting into any kind of answer ban and there was *never* a need to go away of the shade of your oak tree.

Comment: I was tempted to upvote this question just for what I'm presuming is a picture from [The Story of Ferdinand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Ferdinand), because I liked that book... :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Thanks for the reference. (Now the last line makes sense!)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Every Christmas in Sweden there is this cartoon and I still love it...... and I felt it was appropriate to demonstrate low-traffic tag's user vs. the rest of the bulls fighting to get noticed.... (don't get my wrong just putting some color in the post)....

Comment: AFAIK only downvotes can contribute to answer bans. Lack of upvotes has nothing to do with it; you can post 0-vote answers forever and never be in danger of being answer-banned. You are under **no** obligation to go hunting upvotes to offset your other posts with  no upvotes.

Comment: @meagar, your comment fully answer my question, have converted it to answer (community wiki)

Comment: Fyi: The existence of the [Tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badges show that it is not a bad thing to have (a lot of) answers that are accepted, but not upvoted.

Comment: @Sumurai8, Yeah I'm going for 5 Hero badge..... but I was actually a bit worried that my 0 score answers could lead to a answer block....

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Just look at the "answered by ..." list on [your tag of choice](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:5292302+[jasper-reports]).

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand the oak tree / flowers metaphor?...

Comment: @andrewtweber, "The Story of Ferdinand".... we stay under the oak and look at the other bulls fighting.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks, makes much more sense now :)

Comment: I've never even heard of the "Answer Ban" until I saw this in the sidebar -- is there some basic info on what this is somewhere?

Comment: @JohnHascall, http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thank you kind sir

Comment: You seem to be indicating that you see a connection between answering low-traffic questions and receiving an answer ban. There's not. What are you really asking about?

Comment: @TylerH, in answer-bans FAQ, significant number... zero voted, not having experience on SO, answering a number of old questions in low traffic tag, even with good answers I promise you that its fairly easy to get "significant  number" of zero voted.... Basically I was not doing this, but rather only answering new question.... to at least get accepted... and then some rep hunt in java do get 2-3 upvotes...

Comment: @meager, from the [Answer bans FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) : "The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, **zero-voted**, or deleted posts." Does this text need to be updated /changed ?

Comment: @TylerH, I have edit the question to make this issue clear

Comment: How did we get to place where people worry about this?

Comment: @MattStephenson, you published a FAQ, that someone read ; ), and you have user like me that have only been around for a couple of months, answering truck load's of questions....

Comment: In my experience, there are other people hanging out under the same oak tree and they will upvote your answers even on old posts.

Comment: Oh, you say you are "there (3K)" and you see little need to go on. Well... let me tell you, life begins at 10K!

Comment: @MrLister, ; ), you can't have everything in life... The peace under the Oak for me is enough.... for now.. well 3.5 now ; )

Comment: But this site is full of holes when you're not at 10K. All those references to posts that don't exist, all those 404 pages... But now, oh, everything is complete, everything is there! Those deleted messages, oh, those beautiful deleted messages! Everything comes together now! Everything adds up!

Comment: @MrLister I'm with you!

Comment: AFAICT nobody has answered the question as to why [the official answer-ban text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) suggests there may be a problem with zero-voted posts; which question appears to be OP's question also: "The question is, how does this apply "significant zero-voted answers",..."

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes, it remains undisclosed and considering who has commented and answer this question I think it will remain. Why did I accept?, see my 2 comment under accepted answer. The community will help you out, if you have done and honest and fair job.  So I institute a new badge "Ferdinando" that is "Get answer ban without significant count of down voted answers (less then 5%) and more then 30 % accepted answers" this is a platinum badge after the unsung hero.... lets try to get it....

Comment: @MrLister OK you've convinced me to come out from under the tree.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Let's put it this way: if Stack Overflow's ban algorithm gets in the way of **your use case**, then the algorithm needs to be changed. What you're doing is fine and great and absolutely encouraged. It's what SO is meant for. Should the current ban algorithm implementation ever happen to collide with it, this is a bug that needs fixing.

Post back here with concrete details should you ever actually run into problems. Until then, smell the flowers.

Comment: I really appreciate this post (it makes me full of joy to continue, improving my low-traffic tag), during this and next week.  I will post some new answers on old important post where the code has been deprecated (this you can bet will have non acceptance and zero votes for some time), and if I do nice posts, I know who to call if I'm in trouble..... Thanks...

Comment: How the answer ban works will probably remain without directions, I'm accepting this post since if you try to do your best, and you manage fairly well, there is someone out there that will try to help you if you get in to troubles.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Let me put it this way: In your current mode of behavior you are so far away from an answer ban at any point that you can safely ignore the possibility if you keep doing what you're doing ("smelling the flowers")

Answer (score 67):

You have only 1 answer, out of 248, that is negatively voted.

You're fine.

Comment: You don't know if he has any deleted negatively scored answers.

Comment: Sure I have (a couple), the first post on SO was not the best one.... took some time to learn how to answer....

Comment: I rarely keep obliged to keep a downvoted post - especially when people get emotional and downvote because the post violates their internal style guide (I'm looking at you Java programmers).

Comment: @PetterFriberg And if the answer ban hits you, you are (IMHO) in full right to complain on meta and get it waived. That would be a bug in the answer ban, not your failure, and it would need to be fixed or worked around.

Answer (score 47):

Converting [meagar's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314406/can-i-sit-under-my-oak-tree-or-do-i-need-to-go-on-rep-hunt?cb=1#comment293029_314406) to answer:

> AFAIK **only downvotes** can contribute to answer bans. Lack of upvotes has nothing to do with it; you can post 0-vote answers forever and never be in danger of being answer-banned. You are under no obligation to go hunting upvotes to offset your other posts with no upvotes.

This fully answer my doubts, I went hunting for offset votes, see you under the OAK

Comment: If that's the case, then the following bold text needs to change: "The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, **zero-voted**, or deleted posts."  This is from the [answer bans FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).  Or maybe I am misreading.

Comment: @zero298, also I read it like that... that was my worry...

Comment: @zero298, there is a AFAIK (as far as I know...)...  so maybe moving it to community wiki was a bit to much.... I was to happy with that answer???....

Comment: @zero298 that part can also be a bit of disinformation in keeping with the "exact formula is not disclosed" principle. Doesn't hurt to seem more strict than you actually are (well, except when honest people start worrying for no good reason;)

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not the case - the zero voted posts still contribute to the ban...

Comment: @nicael, and Andras feel free to edit the post, if you have more precis information... its community wiki...

Comment: I've already did it to correct the typo :p

Comment: @nicael, I have started to understand, the problem better and I don't think we will see some more detail information, to solve the problem of the order  of these posts, I will accept what I think can be useful for future readers (if you try to do good and you mange doing it fairly well, someone will help you if you get answered ban)

Comment: I think that zero vote answers could potentially land in review queques and if they are not ok potentially have some effect on bans. Or if they are combined with negative vote answers. I guess this is to avoid people diluting downvotes with zero-voted answers. But that is pure speculation, though it would make sense. Another possibility is that you need a minimum amount of answers to be eligible for an answer ban and a few negative + a few zero-vote answers get you there. Putting it there could avoid flaming on meta and that they weren't warned.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful, I actually have not had any problems, the truth is that I have a fairly high accepted answer %, hench the answers are not voted but accepted (aprox. 68 underscored accepted answers).

Comment: I know, but I'm speculating for future visitors and myself. Although they likely will only end up here after they already ran into a ban.

Answer (score 16):

Questions should be answered no matter how old they are. Outdated answers should be replaced with better answers. If you have good answers, go ahead!

Comment: This topic has been touched many times before. Answering old questions appears to be encouraged and appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

it's more than OK to rest on your ass^H^H^Hlaurels, or under your tree, as you prefer. I'm at the stage where I rarely go rep-hunting (except for a burst a couple weeks ago when I wanted to make 20k by new year), but I'll still post answers to things I've needed to know, found no good answers for, and figured out myself.