# Is Stack Overflow really racist/sexist?

Tags: discussion, new-users, blog, welcoming

In [Jay Hanlon's recent "Not Welcoming" blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change), Jay claims in the first sentence that the community is unfriendly to *women* and *people of color*.

I myself never look at who's posting, let alone try to divine their race or gender. Finding out someone's race is typically hard to do for new users (which the article is about - you can only "welcome" *new* users) since the bulk of new users leave the default generated avatar in place and/or upload something non-identifying, and user names are often gender-neutral aliases.

Having seen tens of thousands of posts, I have seen only a couple of instances of racism and I can't recall any sexism; nowhere near enough to warrant there being a trend or even to get a mention.

**Are there any statistics to support Jay's claim(s)?**

---

I just realised what irks me most about Jay’s claims: By saying Stack Overflow is racist/sexist he’s saying that *I* am racist/sexist, which offends *me* deeply. *And* he’s saying that *you* (yes, you reading this right now) are racist/sexist, which I would expect to offend you too. The vast majority of us are here to *help* people.

I ask again: Where is the evidence?!

Comment: *"...Having seen tens of thousands of posts, I have seen only a couple of instances of racism and I can't recall any sexism..."* Speaking as a male (in a statistically-confirmed male dominated occupation) I see numerous comments on SO that simply assume the person is "he". Isn't that sexist? (I honestly wouldn't know because I' not a female.) I try - and usually succeed - to take the time to refer to everyone by name, alias, "OP" or "person".

Comment: I have to say, you said exactly what bothers me about that post way better than I ever could ...

Comment: @dfd - well, if someone writes "You rock, man!" as a comment below your upvoted answer then even if this assumption of gender may be wrong, it still means "mission accomplished", so let's say it's 95% OK. For me. If this is sexism, then by all means let's do something against global warming first. (It may be different for the sister or daughter of this person who seems to think that if someone can solve a coding problem then surely that someone must be male. But isn't solving *their* problems a little beyond the scope of SO?)

Comment: @0X0nosugar, I agree. It's a fine and vague line between being "honestly ignorant" and being "willfully uncaring". I commented before reading all the answers below, and after reading the one with comments - albeit dating back 8 years - I can see where I was addressing the former and not the latter. Also, I *can* see where the blog post may rankle some. For me, I'm not here to be political, I'm here to try to help answer good questions and spread my knowledge.

Comment: @0X0nosugar, almost a year and a half ago as a newbie I had (1) answered when I should have commented and (2) had three downvotes on another answer. I didn't get offended - I learned. As for this "s&%$storm" (if our (US) president can say it, I should be able to right?), I'm done spending time on it. The blog post is flawed, as pointed out by several here and probably should be pulled or at least edited. It's focus paints too broad a picture, and ends up being divisive on a site that, well, isn't about this. Peace.

Comment: @dfd we live with a slightly male-dominated language, where the default gender of an gender-undetermined person is male. There is no workable gender-neutral pronoun; “it” is the only option, which isn’t suitable. That’s why we have the awkward construct “(s)he”. On stackexchange sites, we most often favour the gender neutral “OP”, which shows we actually *aren’t* sexist - we calmly and consistently leave gender to the side when communicating. The evidence is that we are actually actively gender agnostic.

Comment: @Bohemian *"There is no workable gender-neutral pronoun; “it” is the only option"* - this isn't really true. The gender-neutral singular "they" is accepted by plenty of style guides and is probably more commonly used than the gender-neutral singular usage of "he".

Comment: Sacrificing the distinctions between singulars and plurals seem to be bad ideas for us. Honestly, using "he" is not "sexist". It does not constitute any form of discrimination against someone. Comments are usually short and written quickly. They are not essays, prose or legal documents, where all this could *really* matter. It's similar to saying that a comment like "*You can see in the error message..."* is discriminating against the visually impaired. No. It's just short, simple language. (Not a native English speaker here, but ... in German, all this is even more annoying...)

Comment: srsly why do we care that much about a blog post from someone who probably never posted or used stackoverflow and mostly understand how the site works from social media and twitter?

Comment: Do we need gender quotas for the "top" categories, which I dare say, are quite sparse on female entries. You know, like they do at the olympics.

Comment: I don't know why this became active all of a sudden, but now that it was I had the urge to downvote the blog but couldn't. Hmmmmm.

Answer (score 456):

I am a female developer, and I answered "no" to the survey question that asked if you felt as though you are part of the SO community.

Immediately after the survey, they said that a lot of women had replied "no" to this question, and therefore something would be done.

This seems like rather scant evidence of a problem, and I feel that SO took my answer along with others, and used it to support their own pre-conceived feminist ideas, which is not very nice.

Before jumping to the conclusion that women are delicate little flowers needing special treatment, and that SO is sexist, they could have tried to get more information, for example how do people feel about spending a lot of time on SO? (I'm too busy with real life)  or which other internet communities do people feel a part of? (none).

Personally I'd rather have a real life than the Fanatic badge, and in my experience, most women tend that way as well.  Being part of a community implies a degree of emotional attachment which I don't want to give to a bunch of pixels.

My feeling is that the blog post (or at least the part about sexism) is driven by dogma, and now they will scrabble round for as much evidence as they can dredge up to try and justify it.

Comment: You insight that maybe some people don't want to be emotionally invested in an online community is really interesting. It's certainly possible we've misread the data so far. On the plus side, we're not done asking and looking just yet. To solve a problem, you gotta understand it. In the course of understanding, I hope we are open to explanations that conflict with our priors. If you haven't already, would you mind [responding to the short survey](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCQNtu4KHesQz-2AzRSl8z6d4_cLgPj4B7cjNpPePc-04seA/formResponse) from the blog post?

Comment: I suspect that there is such a dearth of evidence that they will be scratching around for a long time.  Unfortunately, the most obvious targets for umm.. 'intensive investigation' are likely to be those who have vociferously argued against the points raised and/or how they were presented in that blog.  My hands are pretty clean, but I'm concerned that directed out-of-context cherry-picking could affect others:(

Comment: If there's a correlation between not feeling like part of the community and being female then that is some evidence towards there being a problem with being welcoming to females. Obviously taken in isolation it can have many different explanations but I wouldn't expect such efforts to begin and end with a single survey. There seems to be quite a bit of assumption making and emotive accusation, coming from a prior stance, in this answer (more heat than light) so I am almost surprised that it has the upvotes it does (except I'm not because people will be people)

Comment: The problem with looking at this data is that it's not done with scientific accuracy or peer reviewed and even if it were, this kind of stuff is often counterintuitive, especially when we go looking for causes. See this for example: https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/02/180214150132.htm

Comment: Great to read a statement like that. Some people are quick at calling "oppression and marginalization" and do not seem to recognize that there also are people who just got themself together, and they are *the majority of the minority (!)*.

Comment: I don't really remember what I answered on that question, but your experience matches mine pretty well. I've never felt singled out on SO because of my gender or skin colour (I am not white), but I pretty much only visit the site while at work. When I'm not at work I simply have lots of other things to do.

Comment: So essentially you and many others answered "no, because I don't really care either way" which Stack Overflow took as "no, because I'm excluded", and then built up an entire unfriendliness narrative around it. *headdesk* This is a prime example of a failure to remember one of the basic, fundamental rules that every developer should know: **correlation does not always imply causation**.

Comment: Related: *[Is there a community on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow sites like there is on Quora?](https://www.quora.com/Quora-versus-Stack-Exchange/Is-there-a-community-on-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-sites-like-there-is-on-Quora)*

Comment: hey I _have_ a real life and the [tag:fanatic] badge. But it's cool to read that answer.

Comment: This is a really good answer.  I've been a daily user of this site for 10 years and I would not say that I feel like part of the community.  It's a large Q&A site, I don't expect it to be a community.  Maybe we have different definitions of "community"?  Maybe I should "hang out" in chats more?  I don't recognize the names of anyone on this page, why would I feel a sense of community with them?

Comment: Your answer alludes to another possible problem.  The question itself is vague.  To you, not being part of the community means you aren't completely absorbed in the site.  To the person interpreting the results, it means you don't feel welcome here.  If different people read different things into the question, do the answers even mean _anything_ at all?  If someone wrote a line of code as vague as that question and as easy to read in multiple ways, it wouldn't make it out of code review.

Comment: "Personally I'd rather have a real life than the Fanatic badge, and in my experience, most women tend that way as well." I'm delighted to hear you say that, because I've always felt that one of the factors causing coding to be so male-dominated is that many women prefer to have a real life. But as a bloke, I'm not allowed to say so. (And I have to say, though I love coding, I find the whole badge/points system on SO incredibly juvenile).

Comment: Are you implying there's something wrong with the [Fanatic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic?userid=1541563)? :P

Comment: On the points by ChrisM, Ian Kemp, and the OP  :  follow-up surveys required, and probably could solicit advice from researchers in the field (both traditional sociology and social media) for terminology and completeness, and from psychometric testers on designing questions to be cross-checking.

Comment: I'd like to +2 this, how can I do that?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The biggest problem is that they haven't added the [“Über-Fanatic” badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/) yet.  =P

Comment: @JonEricson If you're "not done looking and asking", perhaps it would be good to take down the inflammatory blog post that alienates a huge part of your userbase by calling them racist/sexist?

Comment: Calling me a bunch of pixels is pixelist. End pixelism.

Comment: I would like to remind all upvoters of selection/survivor bias (not sure which applies more here). Everybody who ends up _here_, on this question, is already involved with SO in above-average ways. (Yes, I'm saying that taking the time to post "I'm not really a part of this community" is above average. By an order of magnitude.) Similar problemes apply to the developer survey, too. As long as we don't have data on the control group, we have to be very careful with inferences.

Comment: The same goes for the data collected by Jon Ericsson.  I followed the link, and they want personal input and considerable investment of time.  Who is likely to do that?  People with an axe to grind, that's who.  However, we come back to the same point as the question; if you believe that there are many women or non-white people out there who have been scared off SO <i>more</i> than white, male beginners (who can also be quite timid IME), then it's up to you to produce evidence of it before you turn me and others into members of  special minorities.

Comment: @JonEricson re *we're not done asking and looking just yet*: Jay sure thought the asking and looking was done. Has anyone told him it’s not done? Despite the avalanche of outrage and apparent dearth of supporting evidence, his blog post is still intact. Is there any pressure from within from him to retract it or edit/correct the offensive/incorrect parts?

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm not sure what any of that will accomplish. There's plenty of evidence for the claims he actually made, if not for the claims people seem to read into the post. Recently we did a series of user testing of an improved ask page with people who haven't participated much on the site. One common response was along the lines of "this is nice and all, but you know it doesn't solve the real problem, right?" It hardly matters whether or not we are "toxic" if the people best equipped to ask interesting questions _think we are_. That's a start of a death spiral, in my opinion.

Comment: @jon you are right there. I had my hackles up over Jay’s message. The best outcome is what’s best for the site. Could we put some stronger guardrails around posting to help reduce, however large or small the problem is, the use of sexist/racist/hate language by for example putting a language parser that puts posts into a “questionable language” queue for review before publishing if unwelcome language is suspected/detected?

Comment: @Bohemian: Good question. I know we were looking into adding blacklists for terms that just have no reason to exist in comments. Obviously we'll need to avoid the [clbuttic error](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html). I'll need to check what the progress is on that or if it's been misplaced. For what it's worth, the focus right now is not particularly on sexism or racism, but on generally unwelcome systematic "features". We're also very near to showing off a new ask-a-question wizard that might help quality.

Comment: In this interface you are but a wall of text with particular word choices anyway. If you hadn't said you were female I wouldn't have cared.

Answer (score 268):

### No, there's no evidence.

This is due to the insidious nature of the claim, as will be demonstrated.

First, there's a claim which is undoubtedly true:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

There's no question people feel marginalized. This can be proven many ways, but as the blog post says:

> Many people, especially those in marginalized groups do feel less welcome. **We know because they tell us.**

But afterwards, an insidious word change comes in. Although the undeniable truth is that people feel marginalized, the author makes an unwarranted jump; one that is surprisingly subtle:

**He assumes that since people feel marginalized, it's because they were *made* to feel marginalized.**

He makes this logical leap, not in a user-critical paragraph, but in a sanctimonious psychoanalysis allegedly aimed at himself:

> It was hard to accept some of the (valid) criticism, especially the idea that women and people of color felt particularly unwelcome. There’s a weird paradox with bias. Those of us who have privilege, but care deeply about reducing bias should be uniquely positioned to help, but we struggle the hardest to recognize that we are (unintentionally) biased ourselves.² As it happens, ***making* people feel left out is a deep personal fear of mine.**

Now, there is zero evidence that someone who feels marginalized was *made* to feel marginalized due to racism or sexism or ableism or any other exclusatory ism. It's quite possible the user felt excluded due to newbie status, dupe asking, or many downvotes due to low-quality questions. Or it's possible the user simply has a complex. To quote the article, maybe they have a 'deep-rooted kickball phobia' as well.

In fact the only available evidence points to Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow as being inclusive environments, one which is not racist by any means.

> So I focused on what we were proud of: We are one of the only large sites where it’s practically impossible to find a single slur – our community takes them down in minutes. We don’t tolerate our female users being called “sweetie” or getting hit on.

I am not racist. I suspect the vast majority of the users on this site aren't racist. And I deeply resent being told that I am racist.

It's not that I feel resentful; It's that that blog post *made* me feel resentful.

Comment: This. All day this.

Comment: We can play the "no evidence" game forever. There could be a database full of sexist and racist posts, and you could claim Soros paid to have them put there. I can't falsify that, so actual posts in aggregate are not absolute evidence. This is one of the reasons there are often claims of "gaslighting" in debates like this. Again, what's important is what is good enough evidence to justify a particular course of action.

Comment: @Radiodef The problem is that we've had evidence for a very long time that racism, sexism, and other forms of prejudice are not enough to explain these sorts of statistics by themselves. Thomas Sowell gave an overview of his findings on the matter almost 40 years ago: https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8. The talk is focused on economics and education, but the reasoning is the same. A difference in stats when you group people by race, gender, whatever class is very often immediately assumed to imply some kind of prejudice as the cause of unevenness, but this hypothesis rarely stands up to the data.

Comment: @Radiodef If I say 'You're a murderer' and my evidence is someone was murdered, would you be fine with that? It's the same here.

Comment: If I was at the scene of the crime, then it would be a reasonable hypothesis. In the same way, if people are feeling unwelcome on SO, it's reasonable to hypothesize that the community is a problem.

Comment: A hypothesis is not what was put forward, but an unfounded conclusion.

Comment: @Radiodef the 'community' is still just a mixed bag of individuals from all over the world, saying that this mystical group which has no single voice and no single face is a/the problem gets you nowhere. There are surely racists and other less agreeable types in there, that is still only a subset and not 'the community'. Throwing the net that wide will only lead to making even more people feel unwelcome - those that do no wrong at all.

Comment: @Radiodef The key piece of evidence here would be an additional question simply asking _why_ they felt excluded.  That would seem to be necessary information if you wanted to truly understand or resolve this issue, but wasn't part of the survey for whatever reason.  It's not strictly a lack of direct evidence, it's a lack of what would seem like a simple, obvious, easy to collect data point that should be required before jumping to a conclusion like this.  The data they _actually_ collected would support a conclusion more like "we should gather more detailed user feedback about this area".

Comment: @TheAsh I applaud your in-depth analysis.  I have seen and perhaps had some "not nice" comments directed at me.  Even when getting a comment I wan't expecting I never looked at the name and tried to guess the race or sex of the commenter.  But to say that SO is racist is ridiculous.  Stack Overflow rocks.  I've been in CS for over 30 years.  You can't imagine how difficult development was before SO/Google.  You had to bring a mountain of books with you.

Comment: @Radiodef In my experience, people who say "there is no evidence you would accept" have no potential evidence to put forward.

Comment: @JoeCoder Well that is almost a tautology; clearly in cases where you reject all of the evidence you will experience it as there being no evidence at all.

Comment: @11684 There is nothing to reject if he puts nothing forward.

Comment: "There could be a database full of sexist and racist posts" - no, there couldn't, because I **know** there isn't, because **I use the site and I can read the content**. And also because [people have looked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367098/), and what they find simply doesn't evidence a contemporary problem (or a problem in 2018).

Answer (score 141):

I have no more stats than you do. I do know what I've validated as comment flags recently though, and I planned on going through some of those recent flags. I, unfortunately, found the history of what I've handled was lacking in the length of time it's easily accessible. So, I have a much smaller sample size than I originally wanted. I looked at other moderators' recent comment removals and stuck those in here too.

Anyway, in the past 3 hours, we've removed the following comments from the site based on flags the community raised. One thing I'd like to point out is how *old* most of these are.

These are behind a spoiler tag because they shouldn't be on the site in the first place.

> ```
>  Date Posted | Score | Comment
>  -----------------------------
>  2010-03-02 | 7 | why does she want to program?
>  2010-03-02 | 7 | Have you considered sex role playing or mild bondage? I know Python is fun, but there are better ways to spend time with a girl around ;-)
>  2010-03-02 | 1 | import sex import sex.bondage and you are ready to go ;-)
>  2009-09-22 | 36 | Sure they did - you meet a nice girl, club her over the head and drag her back to your cave - very romantic....
>  2009-03-23 | 81 | You asked this question only so you could brag about having a girlfriend, right?
>  2009-08-25 | 1 | Already have that covered - it's called a girlfriend.
>  2009-08-25 | 1 | Whoa! Where did you find a girlfriend who integrates with your source control?
>  2018-04-20 | 0 | A girl coder omg
>  2018-04-28 | 0 | Beautiful answer by a beautiful woman.
>  2012-05-31 | 1 | only ten people have looked at it at the moment. Maybe none of them felt strongly enough either way. In any case, you sound like a overly needy ex-girlfriend :-) But here's a vote to get you going.
>  2014-01-28 | 1 | holy #$%^ that was unreal.....you are the man. would you like my girlfriends phone number? seriously.
>  2016-04-26 | 0 | dw I will :D Can't do it for another 3 minutes it says. Can't leave pretty girls unrewarded huh ^^
>  2010-12-22 | 0 | Are you really such a pretty girl, or is it a fake picture that makes guys answer you questions and vote for them :-P
>  2009-08-25 | 1 | In my trunk! Oh yeah, I went there.
>  2010-12-22 | 0 | Alright, I make this my favorite question then :-) Please don't smoke or otherwise put your life at risk. IT needs human resources such as yourself :o)
> ```

That last one is referencing a user's looks based on their avatar after asking if it was a picture of themselves. The second to last one is answering that comment "Where did you find a girlfriend..." from above.

This is roughly three hours of comment flag handling. It's not a lot of data, and the pattern being flagged right now is definitely skewed toward certain things, but it does paint a picture of what's hiding on the site and has been hiding or ignored for a while.

I'll update this next time I run through the comment flag queue too, to expand on this a bit. It's not a lot, but it does provide some examples of comments that exist (or at least did until very recently) on the site.

Comment: I'll say I'm appalled by the comments. How common is this? As in percentage in all flagged rude comments?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have those kinds of stats. To make it more complicated for the CM team, if they attempt to run stats, these were not all flagged as rude/abusive. Some where just "no longer needed".

Comment: I suppose these comment flags won't carry the rep penalty, so what is your typical response to such flags? Do you mods just remove the comments and move on, or do you take some further actions? Also, do you know if these are mostly from low-rep users or high-rep users (or both)? I'm particularly concerned if high-rep users are involved, because then we potentially have hundreds of such comments lying around on the site.

Comment: @Nisarg If these were posted today, they'd get a warning and suspension. Since most of these are years old at this point, they've been removed...and that's it. As for rep levels, I didn't look before removing them. I suspect, though, that there is some rep to these users at this point just due to the age of the comments. Theoretically, you'd gain some rep over 5-9 years.

Comment: @PasserBy It's worth noting that this isn't the *usual* crop of flags. A few users are helpfully digging through ancient comments with keywords like "she", "woman", "sex", "girl" and the like. It's not like we handle this many sexist comments from 2010 every day - there's just a focus from a few users on cleaning up the cruft that got through the cracks over the last near-decade, which is awesome.

Comment: @Andy I have never understood why we tend to be lenient on old stuff. These comments are so bad they totally deserve to be punished - whether it is through a warning or a suspension, I don't care. If someone committed a fraud (or a worse crime) 10 years ago, they wouldn't be allowed to walk free because it was *10 years ago*.

Comment: @Undo That's great! How can I help? Is there a chat room where we are coordinating this?

Comment: @Nisarg If we're being technical, [often they would](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations). When I see an ancient comment of sufficient nastiness (like these), I always check their list of recent comments (we have a list that includes deleted comments). If they've shaped up since 2010, awesome! If they're still leaving borderline (or worse) comments, I'll handle that as usual.

Comment: I don't think the effort is being coordinated, it's just a few folks using SEDE to run some comment keyword searches.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers would probably be able to get you started using the data explorer.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice rock you turned over. The 2010-and-before comments didn't surprise me. SO was a much more accepting place for all kinds of chatty stuff back then. Granted, that's no excuse, but it's not surprising. The ones from later are the ones that are more disturbing, since this means that *it's still going on*. By then, we were supposed to have standards and all that. The chatty era was behind us. It probably also should be noted that these are the ones that *got missed*. That nobody flagged at the time. God knows what was flagged and removed more quickly.

Comment: @NicolBolas These comments are not *chatty stuff*, they are disgusting. I'm not an old user, but I'm very surprised that such toxic things are considered *not surprising* in 2010.

Comment: @Andy A question... Could all those comments be flagged as rude or would rude flags be declined on some of them? ("Beautiful answer by a beautiful woman" is not rude per se). Do we need another flag type?

Comment: @NicolBolas These comments happen all the time, I wrote about my [own experience with it in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281295/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral/281304#281304). I received stuff like that all the time, when I was actively answering on SO.

Comment: @Modus I'd accept a rude flag on these.

Comment: Waitaminute. Are you saying that there are assholes on the internet? I am shocked. Shocked, I tell you!

Comment: Its pretty much true that people's online personas have very different norms and values compared to their real life ones. There is that lack of accountability - and also the lack of a possibility of being punched in the face that makes people more brave to be bad.

Comment: Are there any other actions taken against the users posting this crap other than the comment getting removed? I think temporary bans (3 days or so) might be justified in some of the cases? Given that the comments are fresh that is.

Comment: @Lundin Yes. Temporary bans occur due to rude comments.

Comment: What do you mean by *"... lacking in the length of time it's easily accessible"* (it seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: What's so bad about _"You asked this question only so you could brag about having a girlfriend, right?"_? Out of context, it seems like the OP referred to having a girlfriend, and that comment is just a joke response?

Comment: Are you really saying that some of these comments stayed up for nearly 9 years and weren't deleted until today?!?!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some numbers about sexist vs otherwise rude comments, in a similar timespan. I mean, how many of such comments are still out there? What percentage of rude comments out there are about sexism? I mean, if _these_ comments managed to stay alive that long, who's to say there aren't a __lot__ of rude comments about other subjects floating around there?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I can only see the last 50ish handled flags for any given moderator. Depending on how active the moderator is, that could be a few minutes (ie. they just cleared 100+ comment flags) or a few weeks (ie. they have been focusing on the back log of custom mod flags).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes. Those were visible on the site until I removed them last night.

Comment: @Cerbrus Regarding classifying the comments: I'm not sure how best to answer that. *I* can't provide that information because I don't have it. But, I'm not sure if others can either because we probably don't know what's out there until someone flags it.

Comment: @Andy: That's more or less the point I'm trying to make. People shouldn't take this answer as proof that sexism is rampant on SO. For all we know, sexism comments may only be a small percentage of all rude comments lingering out there. If anything, __this isn't SO culture. These are bad apples.__ (Maybe I'm overreacting a little).

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm pretty sure you're not, for the some time I've been here, I've never seen such comments. Hence the surprise.

Comment: @liliscent: I think NicolBolas's point was since we don't accept chatty comments in general now, sexist "banter" (and filth) should find fewer cracks to slip through.  As he says, it's no excuse for the old comments, but it's a fact that people were not diligent about flagging sexist comments back then.  And yeah, that is a bad thing.

Comment: @Passer By: Like not even 10%. Maaaaaybe 10% of comments flagged as "rude or abusive" specifically, but even that would be a *generous* estimate.

Comment: @Andy Would you examine the context before accepting a rude flag on these? "why does she want to program?" seems like something that could very easily be said innocently in some contexts, even if it was perhaps insulting in the specific context this instance was found in.

Comment: I did, and in context, it was rude.

Comment: @Cerbrus: "*If anything, this isn't SO culture. These are bad apples.*" You know, people keep conveniently forgetting the rest of that phrase: "a few bad apples **spoil the bunch**." The problem is not so much that they exist; it's that they have lasted *for so long*. And I don't just mean the old ones. We had 2 years to get rid of the ones from 2016.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*Would you examine the context before accepting a rude flag on these? "why does she want to program?"*" If you turn "she" into "he", it doesn't become any less rude. I'm not sure what context needs to be looked into.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Just wanted to confirm. @NicolBolas Imagine this conversation: "My friend hates computers. She'd rather read books all day. She has a really hard time writing code." "Why does she want to program?" In other words, the question could easily fit into a context where it doesn't make sense that the person is trying to program at all; in such a case, the question ceases to be rude and gender becomes incidental. "You asked .. so you could brag about having a girlfriend" might also not be rude if the post somehow spends way too many words bragging about a girlfriend. Context matters.

Comment: @GEOCHET: "*Waitaminute. Are you saying that there are assholes on the internet? I am shocked. Shocked, I tell you!*" This question asked for examples of sexism on the site. This answer provides examples of sexism on the site. Some of them quite old. Declaring that it's not *enough* evidence is basically moving the goalposts.

Comment: @NicolBolas While I greatly appreciate that Andy is practically the only person here who even *attempted* to provide *some* kind of evidence, even Andy admits there are severe limitations to his approach. Namely, he has no data on how common this really is or how many users are exposed or how it affected those who were exposed or how behavior has changed over the years. So it's not really moving the goal post. Just saying that's unsurprising if there are *some* examples of it somewhere. I'll admit that 15 inappropriate comments in 3 hours doesn't seem like a particularly small number, though.

Comment: I've never seen any comments like this in the wild, which leads me to conclude that they are relatively rare in the context of the whole site.  What's important to me is not that such comments appear (not very often), it's that the site is supportive and deletes them.  That situation is OK by me.  The vast majority on SO are well-behaved.

Comment: A really interesting metric would be to compare the level of moderation needed here with that for similar posts in other environments. I suspect YouTube and Reddit would score badly. You are not going to *purge* this stuff from appearing to 0%. The goals should be  IMO: 1) That the ratio of these posts even appearing is very low (e.g. one in 100,000 or whatever counts as low), 2) such posts are handled quickly by the community (again with suitable metric), 3) penalties for posting such stuff is high, 4) Stack Exchange counts in top 1% of community sites for dealing with offensive posts

Comment: Are you so immature that you cant deal with it by just ignoring it?? I dont get it. There will always be people that cant behave that does not mean you have to act like everyone is like that. So annoying.

Comment: OMG I'm wanting to upvote this answer, but am having cognitive dissonance due to the content.

Comment: Some of these are obviously obnoxious, but others I can't really parse without context. And I'm surprised to see *"Beautiful answer by a beautiful woman."* included; it looks pretty typical of the sort of affirmations that I regularly see exchanged between feminist women on social media commenting on each others' professional accomplishments. While *I* certainly agree it should be purged (simply because it's noise), it's kind of an ironic example to have here given that part of the premise of Jay's blog post is that us "Zuckerbots" discourage women by not giving them enough affirmations!

Comment: @SList: Nether have I, but I'm also quite aware that my preferred stomping ground, r, is far from the worst on these things. There are some pretty big cultural differences between the tags, and it's quite easy to make the assumption that your little bubble is a faithful representation of the whole.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm a bit confused. Taking all of those comments at face value (since there's no context) I'd agree that several of them are actually rude, and all of them deserve being removed for at least being too chatty. However, when exactly became something like "beautiful answer by ..." rude, abusive, or even "toxic"? Last time I checked compliments were still considered compliments.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers and Mark Amery: That comment reads like the comment author is flirting with the OP.

Comment: @duplode True, and the reason why it should be deleted as "too chatty". But again, since when did flirting become rude in and out of itself?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm quite sure that a wide majority of women users have absolutely zero interest in getting hit on by a complete stranger while using this site. Is that really surprising? See also: [*Reasonable suggested edit but inappropriate edit summary*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364891/2751851).

Comment: @duplode I would expect that most people here (male or female) aren't interested in getting hit on by strangers. But that still doesn't make the comment rude.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Switching for a moment to a strictly procedural point of view, the only standard flag that refers to the [Be Nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) is "rude or abusive".

Comment: @duplode The only thing I can see in that policy that *might* be applicable here is "this is not a dating site", and I'd consider even that debatable in the case of a single, mildly flirtatious comment. We'll probably have to agree to disagree here. I for one would stick with "too chatty" as the close reason for that kind of comment.

Comment: @MarkAmery Commenting on someone's appearance is inappropriate on an answer about programming.  "Beautiful answer" is fine; "beautiful woman" is rude. Irrelevantly commenting on someone's physical body is, in my experience, almost universally considered rude, regardless of their gender. Additionally, women are routinely [objectified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_objectification), and more emphasis is placed on their appearance than on that of men, which is part why this is sexist. Does that help clarify?

Comment: @NathanHinchey *"Irrelevantly commenting on someone's physical body is, in my experience, almost universally considered rude, regardless of their gender"* - I suspect there are big differences between cultures on this. Personally, the norm I've always observed around me (in real life) is that appearance-related compliments given by women (to a person of either sex) are common and nearly always fine, while appearance-related compliments by a man are usually at high risk of being, at least, awkward.

Comment: First, I want to amend "someone's appearance" to "a stranger's appearance". @MarkAmery Now that you mention it, I have observed a few interactions between women where one complimented the other's body and complimentee seemed pleased. I've also observed this where the complimentee was visibly uncomfortable. Regarding "appearance", I think women's compliments on other women's appearance are usually about things the complimentee controls, i.e. _style_, not _body_. By contrast, I feel like men say fewer style compliments and more body compliments.

Answer (score 88):

There is a tendency whenever sexism or racism is discussed to shift focus *away* from the experiences of those feeling alienated or marginalized, and *towards* one self. This question seems to me to be doing exactly that. To quote:

> Jay claims in the first sentence that the community is unfriendly to women and people of color.

No, he does not. He writes:

> Too many people *experience* Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

This subtle change of focus makes it about something else entirely - about the *intentions* of one group rather than the *experiences* of another. No one's saying that anybody is intentionally sexist or racist - the blog post is about the very specific problem that some groups feel less included than others. Jay even specifically emphasizes this:

> But how do we really know that too many developers experience Stack Overflow as an unwelcoming or hostile place? Well, the nice thing about problems that relate to how people feel is that finding the truth is easy. Feelings have no “technically correct.” They’re just what the feeler is telling you.

And that is what they're saying. I see many have taken to the comment section to this question to imply that no statistics document this, but looking at the [developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#community-do-developers-consider-themselves-part-of-the-stack-overflow-community) it's clear that women are significantly less likely to feel as a part of the Stack Overflow community. Jay and many other consider this a problem.

I see many people claiming that it can't be true because one can rarely determine a person's gender from their username. This could be a symptom of the problem rather that a reason why it can't be. I know of female Stack Overflow users who have two separate accounts - one of them with a male-sounding username which they use to avoid excessive negative comments on their answers. That's a huge problem. And it doesn't matter if it's a general tendency for users to behave that way, or if it's a tiny fraction - if it creates a tendency for one group to feel excluded, it's a problem.

Comment: But it can also be used as an excuse

Comment: @AlonEitan: Which automatically makes the statement untrue? The fact that it *might* be used as an excuse does not mean that it actually is.

Comment: Much of this post is only technically correct. For example, it is technically true that the first sentence of the blog post does not literally claim SO is unfriendly to women and people of color; it is only strongly implied, an implication that is reinforced by later blog content, particularly the parts about bias and the implicit association test link.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't say that, I'm just surprised that women and people of color feel that this community is unwelcoming, and I don't believe that their gender or skin color is a real factor

Comment: And that is why an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366890/476) is important, so everyone’s actually on the same page with what’s being talked about… :)

Comment: Imagine if I had made a blog post saying people were leaving your house with their face punched, particularly women and people of color, and that really it's my fault for letting the situation reach this point and I'll start taking steps to correct it. Would you believe me if I said that no, I'm not accusing you of anything, it's just that people *experience your house as a place where they get punched*?

Comment: @user2357112 When you put it that way, then the answer is yes - I will believe you

Comment: The distinction you make between what the blog wrote and how most of us interpret it is exactly the distinction between how people feel and what SO really is. **I feel** he called me a racist sexist. Just like people here re-iterating we don't down-vote people but content yet people will still take it personally, I find it hard not to take that sentence personally.

Comment: *"but looking at the developer survey it's clear that women are significantly less likely to feel as a part of the stackoverflow community"* - sorry, but I don't interpret 43.3% to 56.9% as an overwhelming proof, just an indication. And the statistics does not tell us anything about the root causes, this is the classical error of mixing up correlation and causation.

Comment: The thing that has really confused me about this whole blog mess is in the basically 4 years I've been on SO, I've never once seen a racist or a sexist remark. The closest to "rasism" would be critique of someone's English. "it's clear that women are significantly less likely to feel as a part of the Stack Overflow community. Jay and many other consider this a problem". I really don't understand how that's our, the community's, fault. Let's assume for a second that women and "POC" do feel less welcome...

Comment: Without any actual racism or sexism taking place, I don't see how that can remotely be tied to us, or how we could fix something that we don't seem to have directly caused in the first place. If I walk into a KFC and decide that I don't like chicken, we'll then clearly I'm in the wrong place, and KFC isn't to blame.

Comment: @Carcigenicate _"I really don't understand how that's our, the community's, fault."_ Well, the blog doesn't say it's your fault or the community's fault. The blog explicitly explains how it's _SO's_ fault. The company is taking blame for this, not blaming us.

Comment: @Kendra "Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women,..." does sound like it's being put on the community, since it's the community that shapes how welcome people feel. But, I'll admit, that's just my interpretation of it. Regardless, I've never seen racist or sexist remarks/policies/anything from staff/the company either. On the contrary, the SO blog has pro-women posts regarding technology.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I interpret it the same as I would _"Too many people experience the DMV as an agonizing place to be."_ It's not exactly the DMV staff's fault that people find the place agonizing- It's the place itself and the processes/technologies they are forced to use. And the post isn't saying that the staff/company _posted_ such things, just that the technology they have created has not helped to create an environment that's _friendly to all_ that come here.

Comment: @Kendra That last bit is what I really don't understand though. How has the system been set up so that women feel less welcome? New users, I get. We have strict, no frill policies that go against experience with other ""social sites"" like downvoting and lack of pleasantries. Women though? Do women require pleasantries and less rigid formats to feel welcome? I doubt that, but I'm also not a woman, so I'm talking out of my ass here. I'm just straining so hard to see where they're coming from.

Comment: As a woman myself... I've certainly seen comments that make me step back a moment and collect myself. Comments that make it feel like the programming occupation is just for the guys. Granted, nothing that's been rude or abusive, and certainly nothing that's hurt me deeply, just things that have given me pause. Could I give you specifics? Not at this very moment, no. I'd have to do some digging to find them again, if they're even still on the sit. Would I call those users sexist? Hell no. In fact, most of the time, it was just casual chatter/banter that just... Didn't quite feel right. (cont.)

Comment: But that's not the system's fault either, I admit. What the system _does_ do is help new users not feel as welcome. When you're already part of a group that doesn't feel so welcome either in your field or in other places where you should be, it's sometimes easy to internalize the unwelcoming feeling of a place and wonder if it isn't just about you. Personally, I think making things more friendly for all will indeed help these groups feel more welcome without even directly doing anything to welcome _them specifically._ Really, it's all about playing to human psychology.

Comment: @Kendra Well, it could be because I'm a guy, so while I've never seen anything blatantly sexist, ya, culture and environment could make the site less appealing to certain perople. That seems like the kind of thing though that would be very specific to people and how they interpret/react to what's being said. Can that necessarily be linked to any groups though?  And if women generally feel out of place WRT technology just because of how male dominated the industry is, that's an inherent problem with everyone associated with the industry. I can't see how SO could fix that.

Comment: And I certainly agree with making the site more friendly in general. Women/POC being mentioned though just seemed like specific red herrings when the real problem is more general.

Comment: Someone posts a question that gets negative feedback. They can do two things with that negative feedback: learn from it, or take it personally and get upset. Could some answers be nicer? Sure they could, and maybe we should keep that in mind. But claiming this has anything to do with sexism or racism smells of pandering to the SJW crowd. SO is remarkably free of politics - let's keep it that way.

Comment: @Kendra, lets's try this: "Too many people experience the DMV as an agonizing place to be, especially women and people of color." Kendra, I am not sure if you're from US or familiar with US politics, but around here these words would be a "disparate impact" statement and would cause all sorts of lawsuits and administrative actions at DMV. In the US context this is indeed an accusation of racism. It should not be, but it is.

Comment: @Arkadiy I program for the DMV for my state. Totally familiar with the US, and also familiar with plenty of people who, like me, would facepalm and try to help control the ensuing firestorm. Some of us try to live in the "should not be" and have our helmets and fire suits for when "but it is" rolls back around.

Comment: The DMV in my county has gotten so much better in recent years. It probably takes the same amount of time (maybe not if technology shortened things) but it feels much less so.

Comment: @BradRichards - how do you distinguish "free of politics" from "in line with politics I take for granted"? I could just as well say that punting on these issues is "pandering to the anti-SJW crowd", since they're served well enough by the status quo.

Comment: Google implicit+bias+debunked

Comment: If the matter is about *feelings*, how about we have a survey on how many people this **blog post** offended by making them **feel** they were called racist or sexist? Surely feeling that you're a victim of slander counts for something too?

Comment: "Comments that make it feel like the programming occupation is just for the guys. Granted, nothing that's been rude or abusive" Either there is a basis for this feeling or there is not. If there is, the comment is clearly violating the Code of Conduct or its predecessors - every version that I can recall - and should be reported as rude/abusive. If such a feeling comes from outside any objective analysis of the comment, however, I would be interested to see a more detailed explanation of the thought process behind it.

Comment: @millimoose the position that "not saying anything is in fact a political statement" is *prima facie* nonsense only endorsed by activists and extremists (of all stripes).

Answer (score 38):

As a person of colour and a fan of SO I was surprised to read the blog post since I have not experienced or heard of someone experiencing racism or sexism. I accept that there can be more to be done in the Software community but I would hold SO in the group of communities that get it right. That being said, I do think that we can improve and it would be useful for the blog post to provide some data. For example, how many users have reported abuse? Is this number going up or down? Are the same users reporting abuse or is it by the general population?

This reminds me of a report done by Uber called ["What can Uber teach us about the gender pay gap?"](http://freakonomics.com/podcast/what-can-uber-teach-us-about-the-gender-pay-gap/) to see if there was gender pay gap on their platform. The study found a gender pay gap but the causes for it were outside of the algorithm which do not allow any inputs based on gender. Male drivers were more likely to be more experienced and more efficiently profit maximising. Female drivers suffered much higher attrition rates for reasons unknown but they also received higher tips which narrowed the pay gap somewhat.

If we apply the same learnings to SO the questions I would like to ask are - how can a more diverse users of SO suffer less attrition (experience) and use SO more effectively (level-up)? There are issues of opportunity, access, tacit knowledge etc. This would help with the jeopardy of misguided, good intentions (you are not the user) and alienating an established group of devoted and well-meaning community.

The blog post pointed out some of the issues by making some suggestions about making it easier to ask questions, improved comment censorship and allowing politeness in questions (I found it weird when someone removed "Thanks in advance" from my early question(s) but I was ok with that). I hope would that these changes would allow a diverse user base to level-up and bring a new cohort of mods who can then self-create the space they need on the site. But without agreeing or being given a useful metric how do we know whether we are getting better or worse?

PS: self identifying on SO feels so weird.

Comment: "*making it easier to ask questions*" Actually, the changes to the Ask Question page are about making it easier to ask *good* (or at least not bad) questions. If you ask up-front for an MCVE, you're more likely to get one before having to close the question for a lack of MCVE, for example.

Comment: @NicolBolas I do like the MCVE suggestion and the proposal for a "SWAT team" of nice users to coach newbies. I think we'll try a few things before we find what actually works.

Comment: I have been here for years, and I don't feel like it is at all welcoming... I think everyone is looking for some semantic twist or typo to call you out on and downplay ideas based on ridiculous minutiae, if I could inactivate my account and leave my answers and questions in place I would do so...

Comment: @GradyPlayer Not to encourage you, but if you choose to delete your own account, all non-negatively voted questions and answers and all questions and answers on meta remain, they get assigned a pseudonym instead (in your case, "user593382").

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes there is that aspect which can make it feel like another rat race sometimes :) is there another online community that you have found to be more successful in this area? Maybe there is something we can copy/learn

Comment: maybe being able to downvote comments? idk.. maybe that would just be another place of vindictiveness... but it seems like if 50 people agree and 75 people disagree the comment still has +50.

Comment: If you were to post with a profile picture where your face is shown as black person you will realize that even when you ask intelligent questions, some people don't even read your questions carefully and they downvote the questions or even close it. Create another account with a white face and ask the same questions and you will not face those challenges. Some people here are racist

Comment: @JohnMax Or.. your one post was noticed by curators for being off-topic while the other one slipped through by accident/luck?

Comment: @Scratte not at all. I have not gotten any post that has been labeled as off-topic. And one of the post I am talking about is one that I am actually now getting answers to because I had to complain about the topic to be reopened ... and obviously people just voted the topic down without even really paying attention to it. And I have people in my office posting the same kind of things but with a white picture as profile and no problem is found with their post, as soon as your profile picture is black, your post is downvoted. You can try it. Use a black profile picture in black community

Comment: @JohnMax I just mentioned it because I do see posts here where curators missed it. I've also seen fine posts being closed and reopened. Not all gets reopened though. I never really pay any attention to the profile avatar. But I know people who attribute their misfortune incorrectly to discrimination. I'm not saying it's not happening, just that it's worth considering. I may try your suggestion out.

Comment: @Scratte I am a CEO of a company. Sometimes I post using my account or I ask some of my workers to post using their own account but with my own words. When I post using my account with the black color it gets downvoted. When thy post using their account where they have their personal black pictures it gets downvoted to the extend that some have given up. One of them has a white picture on his account and no downvote even for the most stupid question but smart questions were downvoted on account with a black face.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Scratte - that's sad to hear but we also cannot be too surprised. We cannot think that somehow we have created an Utopia on the internet - we are products of our societies and unfortunately sexism (i'm male) and racism (i'm black in the UK) are well established. The challenge is what we can do to mitigate this. IMHO we need a countervailing force (representation) to offset the opposing bias and how we achieve that when we (black or female) are the minority is by giving minorities super voting rights. Sorry democracy. But will the majority give up that power?

Answer (score 34):

I want to quote Jay directly because I don't think he says what you've heard:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

He didn't say that Stack Overflow is sexist or racist. He didn't say *you* are sexist or racist. He said some people experience the site as hostile or elitist. Then he highlighted some groups that are especially likely to experience Stack Overflow as hostile or elitist. It's an important nuance because of the nature of the data.

A good place to start is a paper entitled [Someone Like Me: How Does Peer Parity Influence Participation of Women on Stack Overflow?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319244743_Someone_Like_Me_How_Does_Peer_Parity_Influence_Participation_of_Women_on_Stack_Overflow) You might recognize the author, Denae Ford, who helped us with our [mentoring project last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project). Allow me to quote an important finding of that paper:

> Using first names as identifiers as a gender, we define parity as instances where there are many distinct women on a thread and non-parity as threads that have only one distinct woman. We find that although there are less women participating on parity threads, the women on parity threads reengage sooner in the community.

In other words, when women see other women participating on a question (either asking or answering) they are more likely to ask or answer another question sooner than if they don't see women. This study suggests Stack Overflow is not a comfortable place for women because they are a [distinct minority here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#demographics). *Paradoxically, women using names that don't imply their gender might be part of the problem.*

[This year's survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#engaging-together) found women less likely to feel a part of the community:

[image: Part of the Stack Overflow community]

[The survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-race-and-ethnicity) found people of color were also underrepresented:

> Here again we see evidence for problems with diversity and inclusion. We see higher proportions of developers of color in students than professional developers. This year, 7.4% of professional developers in the United States identified as black, Hispanic or Latino/Latina, or Native American while over 10% of students in the United States identified as a member of one of these groups.

Presumably the same dynamic is in play for minority groups other than women. If you don't identify people similar to you, it leaves a feeling that you don't belong.

---

Like many people, I've read ["Suffering on Stack Overflow"](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) and I find many of the complaints misunderstand the way things work around here. Over the years, we've seen all sorts of misunderstanding, including in [academic papers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263138/is-sparrows-and-owls-a-useful-model-of-answering-behavior). It's been easy to dismiss those critics as just not getting it. I've more than once flipped the bozo bit on someone who thought the mere existence of downvotes proved we are terrible people. We've kinda steeled ourselves against these arguments by pointing to the higher cause of content quality.

It obviously isn't clear from the blog post, but we at the company still value content quality. Even people who don't want anything to do with this community admit they use the site's content when they search for programming answers. Thanks to the community's hard work creating and curating content, Stack Overflow is the most trusted name in Q&A. We are committed to quality for the long-haul.

Part of our company's mandate (which is aligned with our business interests, to be fair) is to ensure there is a next generation of Stack Overflow users. If [students find us rude and unwelcoming](https://twitter.com/jessamyn/status/975179501566087168), we might have a problem. If whole groups of people know Stack Overflow as hostile or elitist environment, it will be hard to change their mind. We believe that once you get to know us, the community is an egalitarian meritocracy. But that's not what we (the company) communicate all the time.

Ultimately, getting to know the community is the key to understanding it. We don't have to look very hard to find people who think of the site as a free consulting service or really ought to spend some time learning about basic programming before asking a question or who seem incapable of civil interactions. Telling that sort of user that this isn't the place for them seems like a good idea. The tragedy is the type of person who wants easy answers isn't listening. Instead, people who haven't yet tried the site are learning they shouldn't bother—it's not for them.

Comment: "*It obviously isn't clear from the blog post, but we at the company still value content quality.*" So... why haven't you made that clear in the same venue that started this whole mess? Why is this hidden in some random answer to a random question and not a full-throated statement of support for SO's ideals towards maintaining quality? Equally importantly, why did SE allow such a poorly-written blog post that caused such misunderstandings to be published? If everyone misinterprets what you've said, the problem isn't with them; it's with you.

Comment: I hope you succeed in changing this great community and make it to be experienced as more "welcoming" for new members, but I'm also very skeptical about this - Why should people change, and for what reason? How long will it take for the effect of this post to die out - I bet it wouldn't take too long. I'm able to control myself and not post rude comments, but I do get angry when people posting cr*p, and it gets worse every day - Are you planning to provide us with more tools to handle LQ content (More CV per day, allow to close bad questions more quickly and so on)?

Comment: @AlonEitan: Yes we are. We're taking a more holistic approach, I hope, than we have in the past. For instance, I quite like [this idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367064/1438) _especially_ if we can also knock the number of votes to close/reopen to three. Reducing the number of touches required to beat back terrible questions while also making reopening after correct edits less harsh is a win all the way around.

Comment: @Jon I disagree completely. By saying that specific certain subgroups feel unwelcome, Jay implicitly calls us all racist and sexist. There is no other conclusion, because if the site were just *generally* unwelcoming, it would not make sense to mention the subgroups! His opening volley is that women, people of color, etc feel unwelcome. I think the Jay's post should be torn down. It tarnishes our site and should not have been allowed to be posted without inclusion of concrete evidence that there is significant racism and/or sexism. If no such evidence exists, the post should be redacted.

Comment: Do women say they are avoiding the site because it's unfriendly or not? We just need to ask them

Comment: I wonder how much of the difference can be explained by personality differences. As somebody who scores very high in [trait neuroticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroticism), I absolutely hate dealing with the meritocratic elements of the site. I love writing answers and I love helping people out, but if I didn't there would be absolutely no way I would have stuck around as long as I have. I get a downvote or negative comment maybe once a year, so the problem is entirely internal. I just don't like anticipating negative feedback, even though I get almost none of it.

Comment: Since women score on average higher in neuroticism and agreeableness, you will necessarily end up with less of them in *some* proportion. I don't doubt that there is some amount of sexism on the site, conscious or unconscious, but even if there wasn't I doubt the differences in representation would disappear completely. People with more neurotic and agreeable personalities prefer more collaborative environments over competitive environments and SO leans very heavily towards competitive. I was personally excited about docs, but of course it was a failure.

Comment: How do you square your suggestion of nuance with linking to an implicit bias test and suggesting readers take it? Would this not be for the purpose of identifying that you, the reader, are racist/sexist? I think the reality is that whoever participated in writing that article has let their *own* biases about the issue slip.

Comment: @Bohemian: I think there is another explanation, which is I think what Jon is saying here. If _specific certain subgroups feel unwelcome_, then that is perhaps because (a) they experienced discrimination elsewhere, and (b) with their confidence thus dented, and having heard that Stack Overflow was hostile or elitist, they were cautious or scared to join in, and (c) their drop-out rate would be higher than new/beginner folks who had not experienced a lifetime of discrimination.

Comment: While I agree that people who have not experienced discrimination are likely to be biased about the scale of that problem (_including myself here_) I wonder if that is something of a red herring. I managed to read the whole post without being offended at all, and I don't claim to be especially good at that.

Comment: I find it interesting that people who read "they are saying I'm racist and sexist" into the blog post can't believe that people from other groups possibly sometimes read more than is actually said into content of all types on SO.  Also, that an *implicit* bias test would be about whether you are *explicitly* biased.  I have my own concerns about that test but it does make you think.

Comment: @Elin No one is denying that people can read more into something than is there. However, we're saying two things: 1. When it's *not* there, that's the perceiver's problem, not the speaker's/writer's. 2. The blog post contains content that makes it pretty clear that the author *does* think we're all racist and sexist. It also makes it clear they buy into the rather radical notions that major differences are automatically explainable by prejudice and that prejudice somehow permeates the vast majority of everyone's thoughts and actions.

Comment: @NicolBolas Wait, are you saying that a blog post that said nothing about you being racist or sexist -- that in no way targetted you in intent or wording -- has made you feel less welcome on SO?  And it did so by saying *another group* feels less welcome and they want to fix it?  Unprecidented!

Comment: @jpmc26 No it does not include any such thing, and please stop using the word "we" as though you speak for all people on SO.  Say "I" read it that way.

Comment: @Elin "We" as in the people who disagree with you. And it does. There's a link right at the bottom telling people to take an implicit bias test. Explain that with a reason other than believing a significant portion of the people reading the post are racist/sexist. Then it talks about struggling to recognize bias within ourselves, referring to the community as the "privileged" ones here. The author *clearly* buys into the modern social notion that racism and sexism are deeply ingrained in our psyche and are responsible for uneven stats amoung categories.

Comment: @jpmc26 Sure thing.  You talked about the "perceiver's problem" as though *you don't have it* and you seem incapable of even reflecting on the possibility that you might.

Comment: @Elin Oh, I've asked myself the question before. And I've found that my opinion of a person and my treatment of them is based primarily on values. I know this because I have found that I have enormous respect for women and people of different races who work hard to perform well and who believe in responsibility and don't for men and people of the same race who don't. I've linked this elsewhere, and I think it will help you get some perspective about what is so wrong with the mentality in the blog post: https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8 (The section starting at 18:04 is particularly relevant.)

Comment: _One_ contribution to this perception/experience _could_ be that SO doesn't run user-recommendations/content-filters, so there is no per-user bias toward similarly-minded people.

Comment: What I get from this is that statistically, women will feel unwelcome in a "space" if they don't affirmatively see that other women are around, whereas men don't care. It seems like many people take this sort of result as a reason why women should have special accomodations that men don't get in order for a community to be "inclusive". The same sort of people who are rather fond of aiming that "When You’re Accustomed to Privilege, Equality Feels Like Oppression" [line](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2016/10/24/privilege/) at men. The irony is quite stark.

Answer (score 24):

> Is Stack Overflow really racist/sexist?

## NO.

---

First of all, you cannot deny people's feelings. They do feel what they feel and nobody can tell them that they don't feel something even if completely unwarranted. Including feeling unwelcome because of their gender, race or any other characteristic.

In large communities which Stack Overflow undoubtfully is, you can find all kinds of people. Some of them are and can be categorized as sexists or racists. But community as whole cannot be judged based on behavior of few. Stack Overflow has flagging and moderation systems that actively deals with such abuse.

There is no doubt in my mind that some people may have experienced truly racist and sexist behavior. But there is also no doubt in my mind that such content is long gone and removed from the site. Just the same as spam posts have very short life span here.

In order to call abuse there must be some proof of consistent abuse from larger community (not isolated incidences) and so far I have seen none.

On the contrary, in community where I spend most of my time - Delphi developers - you will hear many complaints that Stack Overflow is hostile place and people are afraid to post questions here. But also the most (if not all) of those complaints are coming from white males that have been coding for ages.

Comment: I'd just like to reiterate that the specific claim made by the blog post is that SO is an unfriendly place and that certain groups of people experience this more, not that people are e.g. posting overtly racist and sexist comments.

Comment: @Radiodef "certain groups of people experience this more" is very dangerous statement. It implies that specific groups are specially targeted. Misdiagnosing the problem can only make the problem worse.

Comment: "Very dangerous" is an exaggeration. I don't even know how to respond to that. It sounds hysterical.

Comment: @Radiodef Hysterical... have you just insulted me based on my gender????

Comment: @Radiodef Actually they clarified and proposed that it was some intersectional thing where bad treatment of new users in general puts off some groups more than others.

Comment: @Radiodef Just kidding... no offense taken... but this is how things can easily escalate....

Comment: @Radiodef It is bad enough that SO is perceived as hostile place... while it is actually not... adding additional assumptions (from official channels) that it is even more hostile toward specific groups will not make things better it will only make it worse. If someone belonging to any of the mentioned groups comes and gets their question downvoted and close voted or anything else, they will not assume they did something wrong - like asking bad questions - they will immediately jump to the conclusion this is because of their gender, race or anything else...

Comment: Frankly I find this entire Q&A to be on the hysterical side. People are offended because Jay literally brought up peoples' experiences and mentioned that implicit bias exists. @DalijaPrasnikar As for that, it sounds like you are saying we can't talk about this. Please again consider the level of speculation that's actually been done.

Comment: @Radiodef: "*People are offended because Jay literally brought up peoples' experiences and mentioned that implicit bias exists.*" I don't see how the reaction can be surprising. If you pride yourself on being a person who treats everyone equally, being told that you can treat people differently without being aware of it is going to be off-putting. It's something a lot of people reject, in part because to accept the possibility of it means to accept that they themselves may unconsciously be sexist/racist, which in their minds is pretty much the worst thing ever.

Comment: @Radiodef I went through an exercise in futility because of the blog post. I never thought as myself as biased, even if I indeed am 'privileged'. I took all these IAT tests... And lower and behold. I had **no** particular bias. The blog post closed with 'do these and you'll be surprised if the results' as if Jay meant 'all of you who think themselves non-biased will realise you are doing this test'.... Which is a bit insulting, if you really know how we act and are. Yes of course we have bad community members. But Jesus do we moderate and delete any 'ism' comment...

Comment: @Patrice You're exaggerating what the blog post implies. The exact quote is *"If you’re shaking your head thinking, “not me,” I’d encourage you to take these implicit bias tests, specifically the Race IAT and the Gender-Career IAT. **If you’re like me, they’re going to hurt.**"*, and it's a footnote.

Comment: @Radiodef oh for sure I quoted from memory and just how it made me feel. You are right the way I quoted it is indeed an exaggeration, apologies for the hyperbole. It is how it's been felt (and resoundedly so) around the regulars though... Probably wrong, in fact very likely. I think the current way meta is makes it clear it was seen this way a lot though

Comment: @Radiodef Frankly, I don't know what post exactly said. I could not get pass "especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups." Yeah, I have read the rest, but my mind could not process anything else.

Answer (score 22):

As others have pointed out, the point that the blog post is making, is that SO is often perceived as a hostile place. And I think the blog post is right, because I too share the perception of hostility.

I am using SO for a little bit longer than 1 1/2 years. This is a comparably short time and I know that other users have gained more reputation points in that time. But I was active on the site on a daily basis, I had the app installed on my phone and I probably spent a bit more time on the site than I should have.

I'm not doing that anymore. I am now only occasionally visiting the site and I have uninstalled the app. And this was not a gradual development, it was a conscious decision that I have made. There hasn't been a single day since where I regretted this decision.

The reason that I backed out is that, whenever I was on the site for a longer time, a certain feeling of negativity (a "bad vibe") was creeping up on me. There is a combination of factors that contribute to this feeling. I am not a beginner. I have a few quesitons and a lot of answers. So it's not even about being unwelcoming to beginners. It is is just too frustrating to use the page for a longer time.

It's frustrating when users can downvote a perfectly good question or answer in full anonymity. It's frustrating when you see users who clearly care more about their reputation than about helping out others. When you see users who'd rather downvote and write a condescending comment on an answer that has a minor error instead of just improving it. When people ask a question without making even the slightest effort to solve the problem on their own first. When your chances to get elected as a moderator improve when you brag about how often you close posts as duplicate with a gold badge. When a new user who is asking a low quality question is facing a storm of downvotes, sharp comments and close votes instead of being explained why his question can not be answered as it is.

And, yes, I have been a part of the problem.

I did make some comments that I wouldn't make anymore. I have been quick to downvote or close a question that could have been saved without it. Not wanting to be a part of the problem is also a reason why I decided to be less active. I almost never downvote now. When I comment, I try to be patient and polite. But mainly my reaction is to participate much less than I used to.

It is easy to be defensive when you're faced with a problem you might be a part of. It's much harder to admit that you too need to change to improve things. So I think everyone should ask themselves what they could do better instead of dismissing the problem right away.

And maybe it is time to at least think about some more radical changes to the site mechanics. What about making all votes non-anonymous (at least to the poster)? What about downvotes only counting for the score of the post, not for the reputation of the poster? I'm not saying to go and change everything on SO; but maybe at least think if the way the site works is a part of the problem.

As for the higher impact of hostility (or its perception) based on race and gender I can only say that I personally have not seen this here. But my personal experience is not the yardstick. It's too easy to say "I have never seen that, so it's not there." Again, it's harder to accept that there is a problem than to be defensive about it. So maybe we should accept that there *could* be a problem and look into it rather than dismissing it based only your own personal experience.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. While I am not a part of any discriminated group, even I notice the normalisation of hostility from time to time. A 49K user has in the last couple of weeks insisted that some of my tidy-up editing was "obnoxious", and he made a point of insisting several times he'd chosen exactly the right word. Mods have got my back, but if it is emotionally exhausting to see a red comment notification, we're doing it wrong.

Comment: I feel welcome here in general, but when I get an anonymous downvote on a question or answer with no feedback, it still eats at me.

Comment: @AnotherParker I'm guessing your not so eager to get to the bottom of the reason for each upvote you receive, though? I know downvotes don't always speak for themselves, but if we can't accept them without an explanation, then they are worthless.

Comment: Kudos on your fifth paragraph.  I get so tired of seeing (and sometimes receiving) downvotes with no explanation.  Even if someone wants to just be rude and selfish and to show no concern for the other person, they should realize that downvoting without explaining will do nothing to eliminate the problems that get the downvoters all in such a tizz in the first place.

Comment: I don't always leave a comment with my downvotes. Sometimes I just downvote the question or answer and upvote a comment that someone else already left.

Comment: Removing anonymity impedes honesty.     I'd suggest a more thorough introductory section on  _why_ people are brusque , what's tolerated and not , how much code is necessary for a good answer, how much code is necessary for a question, etc  for new users, which blocks karma use until the pages have been at least glanced at.   Also bear in mind there's also a generational interaction here that you might not find on many other sites: a lot of the content and techniques are, intentionally, long-lasting  ,  while the cultural norms shift.

Comment: @halfer You are part of a discriminated group. You are an active user on Stack Overflow. Have you ever taken a look on some people's opinions of SO users on Reddit or the like? We're definitely discriminated against. (This is meant to be a joke, I do not mean by this to minimize in any way discrimination against women, minorities, or anybody else.)

Comment: @WillC: You have a user who takes a considerable amount of effort and puts out a post with their name on it. And then you have the voter who in a split second can approve or disapprove on what the poster wrote *without* having to put their name on it. That is a disparity. When you have an opinion, you should be ready to stand behind it and defend it when necessary. So, the removal of anonymity is a step towards integrity. And integrity fosters honesty.

Comment: @AnotherParker and others: oddly, I don't mind downvotes so much. I guess I spent so much time telling people that downvotes are not personal, I internalised that advice myself `:-)`.

Comment: @Clay07g Why should I ask for extra praise from someone who liked what I did? I want to improve and get better. If I deserve a downvote I'll gladly accept it, but isn't the whole purpose of the stack exchange network to get better at things?

Answer (score 14):

I was under the impression that there are no women or people of colour on Stack Overflow, only programmers.

I'd also venture to suggest that anyone who comes to Stack Overflow and identifies as anything other than a programmer bears full responsibility for any resulting damage to their feelings. Identity is a many-faceted thing. Sometimes I identify as a father, for example. Sometimes as an Englishman. Both of those are non-square pegs and I would have nobody but myself to blame if I were to fail to hammer them into Stack Overflow's square hole. Irrespective of the importance to me of either of those facets of my identity, neither of them is remotely important to SO and it's not SO's job to cater to them.

Newer coders are an entirely different matter and entirely within SO's wheelhouse. They come to the site to get their specific questions answered. SO exists to both answer those questions for this specific newbie and to enshrine question and answer for the benefit of future readers. Both parties should be aware of this, if the newbie isn't aware that's an onboarding problem which SO can and should solve. One problem can best be summed up as the question being "I keep losing my grip on the screwdriver while trying to drive in this nail, what can I do?" To which the top answer should be and frequently is "Use a hammer instead". The newbie may take exception to this, but that falls somewhere between their failing to take into account the objectives of the site beyond getting their own specific question answered (which is SO's problem) and their feelings (which are their own). Both can be mitigated by better onboarding but SO's responsibility to the horse ends at leading it to water. Maybe [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) needs to be surfaced better and the user should be asked to confirm that they've read it and are abiding by it to the best of their ability. I'd suggest it could be restructured into a numbered list for ease of explaining precisely how a question is low quality.

The other side of the perceived hostility problem is exemplified by (but not limited to) hurried or careless veterans erroneously marking as duplicate. Sometimes the "duplicate" post isn't actually the same problem as the newbie is experiencing because of a version mismatch or a change in best practice that the veteran has failed to take into account. Sometimes simply marking as duplicate fails to supply the context that would enable the newbie to make the connection between their question and the duplicate. The greater the disparity in knowledge between the teacher and the student, the more empathetic the teacher has to be in order to account for what the student doesn't know that he doesn't know.

Comment: There are women and people of color on SO.  I mean I guess you know that, but denying our existence is not a particularly great starting point.  Actually why don't you say "there are no men or whites on SO" instead?   That would be a more dramatic opening if you really want to go in the direction of denying people's identities.

Comment: @Elin Maybe the most neutral wording would be... "there are no men or women, or people of color or whites, on Stack Overflow".

Comment: Even better, though still factually incorrect ;-)  it is okay a rhetorical point.

Comment: Wait wait. You're saying that someone's personal identity, however they choose to define it, is automatically unacceptable on SO, except for the "programmer" facet of their identity?

Comment: @AnotherParker That actually seems very fair. It is a programming site, not a Pride parade.

Comment: Truth be told, even "programmers" is too specific. Its a site for programming problems, not specifically programmers. I like "visitor". It doesn't matter if you're a person, a cat, a bot, a script, Community - all visitors.

Comment: "_I was under the impression that there are no women or people of colour on Stack Overflow, only programmers.  I'd also venture to suggest that anyone who comes to Stack Overflow and identifies as anything other than a programmer bears full responsibility for any resulting damage to their feelings._"  I'm pretty sure it is this exact sentiment that the blog post is trying to point out.  Are you really trying to whitewash the other aspects of my person and reduce me to only a programmer?  People from different backgrounds think differently.  Which is relevant to how they approach programming.

Comment: @AnotherParker "Unacceptable" is a bit of a loaded term. "Irrelevant" or "off topic" would be better.

Comment: @Gimby If you've written a Hello World and are pursuing programming topics on SO, you're a programmer. If you're a bot or a script you have no feelings. If you're a cat I invite you to look at this fascinating red dot instead.

Comment: @ryanyuyu There are entire sites dedicated to placing undue importance on the things that divide us. Stormfront, for example. I prefer to spend my time on SO, which is dedicated to the things that unite us like "Why does my fscking code refuse to run?" and "Why does our PHP dev keep eating my crayons?" (Before anyone gets huffy: I'm a PHP dev myself and the purple ones are delicious).

Comment: And the blog post is just trying to further the goal of uniting more people.  Their point is that certain groups of people are self-reporting feeling less a part of the otherwise homogeneous community.  SO is just trying to determine what kind of issues might cause this.  We agree that there is hardly any overt discrimination against minority groups, but perhaps the overall structure or other interactions hide a bunch of subtle yet important inherent biases.  SO is not calling us racist/sexist/whatever.  Just that they're looking into the overall system with another perspective.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The blog post makes it pretty clear that they're only approaching this from the perspective that it's the community's fault and the community's inherent biases when it's equally likely to be the minority group not checking their own biases at the door like everyone else. It was one tired sexist cliche away from referring to women "breaking into the boys' club". Well, this is the "boys' club", a field invented by a woman where everyone's already equal. I don't belong to any other one and I'm not responsible for any greener-grass misconception someone formed from the outside.

Comment: I'm really saddened by the amount of focus being devoted to identity politics in these comments over the new user experience that made up the majority of my answer.

Comment: @ChrisCox From the blog: "_The real problem isn’t the community — it’s us:_" sounds like it's not casting blame on the community?  Also, regarding your other complaint about the "identity politics", your first sentences is literally, "_I was under the impression that there are no women or people of colour on Stack Overflow, only programmers_".  While I understand what you're really saying (that SO is supposed to be identity blind), that statement comes off as almost saying that literally there are few women and minorities here because those people aren't programmers. Perhaps you want to edit?

Comment: @ryanyuyu The immediately following statement uses a value of "us" that's barely distinguishable from "the community". Only the provision of tools is something concretely attributable to the organization rather than the users. My first sentence specifically addresses the two facets of identity specified by the blog post. While I could technically edit in a laundry list of possible identities such a list would never be comprehensive and thus far even the folks who seized on it to the exclusion of the other 75% of what I wrote have had no issues understanding it so I'll let it stand.

Comment: @ryanzuzu 2/2 because poxy character limit: If anyone genuinely has trouble understanding that "women", "people of colour" and "programmers" are not mutually exclusive sets they're on the right network to find someone to explain it to them.

Answer (score 3):

Better to say, there is a bias against beginners on Stack Overflow. Sometimes women and minorities are such.

Beginners have hard time to formulate a question that has a definite answer because, they're, well, beginners. They do not have the necessary concepts, technical expressions. They get downvoted and closed easily.

I was banned from a Stack Exchange site because of that. Usually I do not ask questions on topics I am professional, I ask when I am a beginner.

Comment: You might wish that the bias is only against beginners. That is too easy. I have now seen enough anecdotal evidence from those directly involved that solely focusing on beginners is the wrong thing to do. Don't  exclude beginners either but there is more to do beyond that.

Comment: Would you say that you were unable to formulate your first question on SO? What about Jon Skeet? Remember, you and him where a beginner.

Comment: @rene reducing the 'crappy question' income rate has a good chance of cooling down a bunch of people which may behave better (i.e: keep their rudeness/positions for themselves) in comments. This doesn't mean rude comments should be tolerated, but I'm convinced less bad questions would also reduce the rude reception, so improving the guidance on how to ask is the 1st step to make IMO.

Answer (score -8):

I can't imagine that the Stack Overflow *website* is racist or sexist by design. However, when it comes to racism and sexism most people don't really *get it* and I wouldn't expect a developer community like Stack Overflow to be any exception.

> I just realised what irks me most about Jay’s claims: By saying Stack Overflow is racist/sexist he’s saying that I am racist/sexist, which offends me deeply. And he’s saying that you (yes, you reading this right now) are racist/sexist, which I would expect to offend you too.

I appreciate the self-insight. Yes, I expect those sorts of claims to offend most people. There are some fundamental psychological patterns at play here, one of which is that nobody likes to be criticized. And the accusation of racism is particularly heinous, which in a way is something to congratulate our society for.

Another pattern is that people respond to criticism by fighting against the criticism rather than considering it as a suggestion or a way to improve. When documentary filmmakers suggest ways to improve the USA they get called anti-American. When the Hamilton cast expressed their hope that the Trump administration would do their best to represent all Americans, the Trump administration demanded that the Hamilton cast apologize. When Colin Kaepernick took a knee, did the audience respond by recognizing the need to improve? Instead of fighting the thing he was protesting they fought the very fact that he was protesting, the idea being that he shouldn't suggest there's anything wrong because that's an attack on America.

So there's always this question of what's more important to us. Is our dedication to preventing racism/sexism greater than our desire to avoid being called racist/sexist?

There are some men who take great offense when a woman takes precautions on a first date, these men saying that it's as though she's assuming he's a rapist. But I say her safety trumps my feelings on this matter. There are some adults who similarly take offense when they feel a parent is accusing them of being pedophiles by not wanting them to babysit, but I say go ahead and play it safe. My feelings aren't as important as your child's safety.

When I say that most people don't get it, am I claiming to get it myself? Not necessarily. But the difference may be that I recognize my blind spots and make a continuous effort to improve. I know that as a white man I can't say that the police in my town are really nice because there's a huge part of the human experience that I'm oblivious to.

So is Stack Overflow racist or sexist? I think we all recognize that race and gender issues are completely off-topic for Stack Overflow and I'm not entirely sure how racism and sexism would come into play because most users are sort of anonymous. So it's understandable that most of us would react to claims about racism and sexism with shock and confusion. I believe the playing field here to be fairly even, and I think the attempts to even the playing field further may be largely based on misunderstandings and misinterpretations of poll results.

However, we all have blind spots, and it's not up to me to decide if the community is welcoming to women and racial minorities. If you're trying to demonstrate respect for a group of people, those people's subjective experiences should be considered and not ignored. Marginalized groups are probably tired of always having to provide some kind of logical proof for the microaggressions against them, so it may be better to just believe them. If we want to help, we could try suppressing our egos and growing a thicker skin so that when we're called racist or sexist, our first instinct is to ask "How can I improve?" rather than "How dare you?"

> The vast majority of us are here to help people.

Comment: As already discussed elsewhere: In fact, he did not *explicitly* say that SO is sexist/racist, but made claims that strongly suggest this. (An implicit bias to allege an implicit bias, so to say). One main critique for the blog post is exactly that: He (seemed to) pull this out of thin air, and weaved into the blog post. OTOH, for no obvious reason. OTOH, it's hard to imagine that he was **not** able to foresee that this would cause turmoils. You'd not ask "How can I improve" when being called a racist without cause, repeatedly, or seemingly just for provocation...

Comment: @Marco13 Repeatedly? Was there more than one post?

Comment: @Clay07g It's not just questioning claims. The OP was explicit about taking personal offense to it. It's worth noting that everything goes both ways. It seems to me that some people go around proclaiming that other people take offense too easily without applying that reasoning to themselves.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that this was the first time that you have "implicitly" been accused to be "implicitly biased" (basically, because you are "white"). Personally and subjectively, when someone called be a racist, I'd neither ask "how dare you" nor "how to improve", but rather: "When does this cr4p finally stop?" (I'm really tired of this, and I think that crying wolf like this will do more harm than good in the long run). I also think that some people overreacted to the post, and should stay calm, and simply request it to be reworded for clarity. But until now, SO leaves us dangling ... :-/

Comment: I know for a fact that I am biased. We all are. And if we're both white and we both share these common experiences like you said, it may be worth asking why implications of racial bias bother you more than they bother me.

Comment: We're on  a meta-level here. And I'm rather bothered by the persuasivenes of being called "racist" (for **no reason at all**) than for being called this at all. In **one** case, you could argue calmly and objectively. If this is a general baseline of *any* discussion, it's just annoying.

Comment: "When documentary filmmakers suggest ways to improve the USA they get called anti-American. When the Hamilton cast expressed their hope that the Trump administration would do their best to represent all Americans, the Trump administration demanded that the Hamilton cast apologize. When Colin Kaepernick took a knee, did the audience respond by recognizing the need to improve?" - the issue here is that "documentary filmmakers", the Hamilton cast, Kaepernick etc. don't actually do the things you imagine that they do, and instead do much more objectionable things.

Comment: "But I say her safety trumps my feelings on this matter.... My feelings aren't as important as your child's safety." Will you say the same sorts of things when the concern for "safety" comes from a group you *don't* consider a noble activist cause? My expectation - based on over 15 years of seeing arguments like this one presented on the Internet, hundreds of times - is that you will not; instead, you are likely to point and laugh. (I have also found that such activists generally don't care about the hypocrisy, often not even seeming to think hypocrisy represents a moral failing in general.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - What are you suggesting is not a noble activist cause?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I didn't suggest that about anything in particular. The point is that *there presumably exist* things that other people want to see happen ("activist causes") that you personally strongly disagree with (perhaps because, for example, you would consider them "reactionary", or in other ways proposing a change opposite to the changes you would like to see). And my question is, when *those* activists complain of "feeling unsafe", will you care? Because my extensive personal experience has been that typical proponents of such "safety" are happy to attack others they disagree with.

Comment: I was talking about keeping children safe from abuse as one of several explanatory examples. It seems like a non sequitur to expect me to prioritize the safety of reactionary hate groups like that's required for moral consistency

Comment: ... That response makes it pretty clear to me that you are not interested in a good faith discussion.

Answer (score -11):

Something I think a lot of people forget about when talking about this sort of thing is that racism and sexism don't only refer to outward hate, but also structural racism/sexism. Structural racism/sexism is when there is some factor within a system that results a preference or bias toward a group on the basis of race or sex.

According to the blog post you're referring to, they have data that shows women and people of color feel less welcome here, and that on it's own shows there is structural racism and sexism. There is something about SO (the site, the rules, the format, the community, or any of a large number of other factors) that is causing a bias favoring white men. We should all be looking at our own behavior to figure out whether we are contributing to this bias or not, and we should also be looking for other things on SO that could be part of the problem so we can make suggestions on how to improve it.

The existence of structural racism or sexism doesn't necessarily mean the participants in that system are racist or sexist (though it's always possible they could be a factor), it does mean, however, that we should all be looking for ways we can help improve things so that everyone can feel they are part of the community.

Comment: Are you sure this is something systemic on SE and not merely a reflection of the wider field of programming, which is famously not equal in terms of participation? Put simply, if there are proportionally more men in programming in general, wouldn't even a perfectly egalitarian Stack overflow resemble that makeup?

Comment: @user5389107 They were asking about whether users felt they were part of the community, not looking at the raw number of users of each sex or race. Women and people of color don't necessarily need complete parity to feel comfortable in a group, though it absolutely helps. There are plenty of other things we can do to make them feel part of the community while the makeup of programmers in general is not even. Also, while there are more white programmers in the US than non-white, there are people from other countries on SO (like India), so the raw numbers are probably more even than you think.

Comment: Question asked for proofs, you come with theories.

Comment: "Structural racism/sexism is when there is some factor within a system that results a preference or bias toward a group on the basis of race or sex." What factor? What preference? What bias? What evidence? When you don't see men at the knitting circle, does that evidence an anti-male bias or preference resulting from structural factors?

Answer (score -16):

I'm black, so maybe my answer is emotionally biased. I recently asked a question and it was closed almost immediately  and I felt like it had something to do with the way it was or wasn't worded. I worded it as best I could. It felt like, if you don't speak and write like us go away. Or maybe I'm not as smart as you all and just don't belong on stack overflow. Like I said, maybe I'm biased. But having non blacks talk down to me and basically ignore my questions makes me feel discriminated against. But that's life in america right

Comment: You are 100% sure it was not your question that was reason for how it was moderated? Most of the time we can clarify which improvements are possible for a post and/or provide you with extra guidance, when asked on Meta. Feel free to give that a try as well.

Comment: I'm black (as in, African-American) too (ironically my [Medium profile](https://medium.com/@makotothedragon) is the only picture I keep of myself on the internet these days).  Your question being closed has ***nothing*** to do with your race, ethnicity, color, creed or beliefs.  It's the simple fact that your question didn't match up to the standards of the site.

Comment: @Mik despite many questions seeming to *require* site users to be psychic to answer them, they are not in fact psychic. And sorry to pop your balloon here, but *no one* on the planet is "psychic". Because you profile does not contains any clues as to your ethnicity/race, your perceived discrimination exists in your mind only.

Comment: ^ The same goes for the *assumption* about race, gender, beliefs and sexual preferences of those people helping you.

Comment: Having had a look at your question, there's nothing wrong with its wording. It's simply a somewhat vague problem which isn't reproducible with the information provided. That is all, and that's the only reason it's been deemed off-topic. There's absolutely no hint of your race or anything in there that would make that a criterion.

Comment: This answer is interesting, in that it demonstrates that the following two situations are simultaneously possible, despite seeming to be contradictory: (1) A StackOverflow user honestly feels discriminated against on the basis of race; (2) Empirically, absolutely no discrimination on the basis of race on the part of voters  / commenters / answerers / moderators actually occurred.

Comment: @Makoto Wow, TIL… Just goes to show that what I always say is true. Nobody knows or cares what your bag-o’-flesh identity is here. We only care about the content you post.

Comment: [Remember: on the internet, nobody knows you’re a dog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366654/4642212).

Comment: @JonSchneider it's not contradictory at all. Some people are just predisposed to expect discrimination against them. This has at least as much to do with their individual upbringing, socialization and education as it does with any base rate of discrimination against any particular group they happen to belong to.

Answer (score -17):

I hate to have to keep saying this, but the evidence you're looking for is in the comments to your question...

> This doesn't seem like a duplicate, @Makoto. This question is specifically asking for evidence of racism or sexism, while the duplicate is not. I think the question here is confused - I think Bohemian, like many other confused commentators on Meta, doesn't speak intersectional-feminist-ese and has failed to recognise that what a woman or non-white person is said to "experience" in that language needn't have any relationship with objective reality - but Bohemian's failure to understand the intended meaning of the blog post notwithstanding, this still isn't a duplicate.
>
> You may or may not be right about whether women/POC/others disproportionately feeling the site is hostile is would be strong evidence of discrimination, but that's explicitly not the thesis the staff have put forward; rather, per Tim Post, it's that women and POC are more emotionally fragile than white men, and so "experience" hostility and elitism that a white man would not "experience" when they hear or read exactly the same words as the white man does.
>
> if certain (coloured/female/etc) people are more brittle, that’s their problem, not restricted to SO - it would affect every aspect of their life. It’s not reasonable to put that responsibility on to SO. AFAICT SO is secular and blind to race. If we start treating certain people preferentially, that would be unfair to the rest (and nearly impossible to make work).
>
> I think you are missing the point. Fine, let’s be more welcoming. But why did Jay even mention women/POC. That’s what I am calling out as bullshit. If you’re going to write that in the first line, you better have some evidence. So, (in jerry maguire style) Show me the stats!
>
> People don't know your gender on SO until you tell them using your picture or your name. If you don't like the consequences, real or imagined, then stop telling them. All the material on SO concerns machine interactions and your gender is utterly irrelevant. This applies not only to girls but also to people with other notions of gender identity. Until you supply this information, other people's prejudices are not your problem. Keep it that way.

**You want the proof, it's staring you in the face and even coming out of your own mouth...**

It seems Stack Overflow's entire defense against being called racist, or sexist, or homophobic, is to claim "we don't talk about that here, so it isn't a problem. We obviously don't have any implicit bias, because we're not allowed to say explicitly biased things."

But take a real hard look at what it looks like when you do talk about it. Let it sink in for a moment. Imagine how your words sound to one of those "brittle" groups you mentioned.

One such user even said it:

> ...As an African-American, all I can do is sit here and make a face at what you just said. Congratulations on missing the entire point.

In your rush to defend yourselves you're exhibiting the exact sort of behavior that you claim isn't a problem. Your implicit bias has become explicit and you should be ashamed of yourselves. But instead of taking a step back, and really seeing it, you're patting each other on the backs and congratulating yourselves for not being worse...

It's been said,  but it's worth repeating, congratulations on missing the entire point.

---

I'm just gonna go ahead and leave this here, for those that really need to see a black and white mathematical explanation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrie_multiplier

> The Petrie multiplier is a thought experiment[1] or mathematical model[2] invented by British computer scientist Karen Petrie, and first described by Ian Gent in 2013.[3] The multiplier "shows that if the percentage of men and women in the room who make questionable remarks to the other sex is equal and the percentage of women in the room is lower than the percentage of men, then the average woman experiences far more sexist comments than the average man."[1]

Comment: While much of the material you quote is offensive (such as the concept that certain groups are brittle, or that people should have to hide their gender), the concept that women and "people of color" are brittle isn't something Bohemian is supporting. People are saying that specific *Stack Overflow staff* believe women and "people of color" are brittle, and Bohemian is saying that even in the hypothetical case where this brittleness is real, we shouldn't give specific groups preferential treatment.

Comment: The whole thing reminds me of a time when I was on a project and pointed out a gender issue.  The person I was talking to (this was just a casual observation) went into a male only chat and came back to me a while later and literally, I kid you not, said "I asked the guys and they all said there are no gender issues."

Comment: I want to cry from the frustration of all of this but then I risk people calling women on this site "over-emotional" and "too much in their feelings"... This is why I never brought up how the previous SO philosophy (which is a philosophy commonly used outside of SO) sucked in tech groups anywhere, which is something people are probably going to bring up to ask "well, why haven't I heard any of these concerns before???".

Comment: @astrocat1997 Times they are a changin... maybe... hopefully... Hang in there.

Comment: Damned if you do, damned if you don't. '

Comment: The post accused people of bias. People got annoyed, because they aren't biased. Other people said no you really are biased, you just don't know, while others said, no we didn't mean you are biased, it is just intersectional from how you treat new users. How do you defend yourself against that kind of argument. It is non-sensical.

Comment: *"Imagine how your words sound to one of those "brittle" groups you mentioned"* - I'd think *I'm glad to be in a community of people who will just damn well interact with me as their equal professional peer and don't put any stock in feminist ideas about me being a helpless victim who needs coddling.* I'd think *I'm glad this bullshit is getting rejected, because I want to be able to succeed on my own merits and don't like the idea of interacting with a community that's internalised the idea that I can't participate equally with them because of my sex or the color of my skin.* This isn't hard.

Comment: "Stop being a rapist!" 
"I am not a rapist..."
"That is EXACTLY the kind of thing a rapist would say!"

Comment: @Radiodef: For example, "Until you supply this information, other people's prejudices are not your problem." That translates to "if you're a woman/black/etc, ***hide that fact from everyone*** and you'll be able to pass for a white male and have no problems". I think it's pretty clear why some people might have a problem with that and similar statements.

Comment: There's all too common trend that's over 50 years old of assuming that *differences* between groups necessarily implies prejudice as its source, and this is simply not the case. (If you want evidence of that fact, I suggest looking into Thomas Sowell's work: https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8.) In the face of this all too common fallacy *and* the fact that race and sex are not readily identifiable on SO, asking for actual evidence of racism or sexism *motivated behavior* is entirely reasonable. Furthermore, claims that even posing the question is equivalent to denial are unhelpful and insulting.

Comment: Furthermore, "We don't talk about that here, so it isn't a problem. We obviously don't have any implicit bias, because we're not allowed to say explicitly biased things," is a gross misrepresentation of what's being claimed. What's actually being said is, "If I can't identify people's race or gender, how can I possibly treat anyone differently based on it?" Maybe you have a point that being told not to make that information available is rude, but you're taking that one tidbit and trying to claim there's massive evidence of disgust for entire classes of people.

Comment: Brilliant answer - of course it's downvoted. Impressed you could remain calm and factual, you've done a better job at that than me. Keep up the good work. Ping me if you ever feel you need a friend or support. I'm saying this not as a mod, but as another person,

Comment: @YvetteColomb It's really disappointing that one of your fellow mods is implicated here. I'm not sure what more can be said or done about it, but it's certainly disappointing.

Comment: The systemic shouting-down to any answer or comment that points out *that there are actual, verifiable examples* of unwelcoming behavior in these discussions *made by people who are claiming there "is no evidence"* is incredibly disheartening. While there may be valid issues being raised by people complaining about the blog, they're being drowned out by the people who are making it clear that not only is there a problem, but that the side supporting problematic behavior **is in the majority**.  I've cut off almost all my SE activity as a result.

Comment: @apaul I think a very large part of the frustration in the community right now comes from the fact that the existance and influence of implicit bias is not a widely accepted concept and quite offensive to the people who don't accept it. It seems like everyone is starting from different presuppositions here and nobody is even arguing _about_ the same thing, so obviously the discussion gets frustrated and heated. It's really unfun to watch from the sidelines.

Comment: "Implicit bias" isn't a coherent concept. It's something that was made up by people who couldn't find evidence of actual bias, so that they could go on to advocate for actual bias in the opposite direction. "We aren't allowed to say explicitly biased things" clearly is, and should be considered, the standard for treating people equally and courteously. The Petrie multiplier can't turn zero into non-zero.

Answer (score -21):

Jay Hanlon is right about SO being pretty elitist, rude and not being very welcoming. I addressed this myself in my 2015 article [The decline of Stack Overflow](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d), which currently has 347,000 views, 1,970 likes and 146 comments (after going viral twice).

The vast majority of the comments on my article are moderately to extremely supportive of its content. Here's just a handful of those comments:

> I have been a contributor for many years. Lately i have felt that the
>   site has become more bully. I think stackoverflow.com should come with
>   a warning that “Don’t join this site if you are not a pro, or you
>   don’t have a masters degree in english, or you cannot guess how the
>   vaguely written forum rules are interpreted by existing gangs on the
>   site”

> I’ve thought about and wanted to write an article like this so many
>   times it’s just unbelievable. A few years ago Stackoverflow was
>   amazing. In Its origins I loved using it, but i am honestly scared to
>   post on it anymore. While i still read answers on it frequently the
>   fact of the matter is the gamification of it and sadly somewhat
>   socially inept “experts” that often run it mean the stakes are just to
>   high which Make it almost impossible to post on. Programming sites
>   might be better if a user could award a title to a user and focused
>   less on punishing users and scaring them away. It needs to figure out
>   a system that rewards considerate users and lets trolls be tucked away
>   in their caves where they belong.

> Basically, the SO moderators are guys with personality problems. SO is
>   a “venting outlet” for them.
>
> Either you are a professional interested in your work or you spend
>   your day long downing others questions/answers. It is a way to grow up
>   in your own eyes, to forge a personality, otherwise you do not have.
>
> More or less all question-sites are having the same problem. Human
>   nature. Or better said “stupid-human nature”.

> I’ve used Stack Overflow for years, as someone who occasionally
>   browsed the site for answer to simple HTML/CSS related issues I had.
>
> I recently created an account to start answering questions and asking
>   occasional question about JavaScript projects I’ve been working on.
>
> The collection of thoughts, quotes, and links you have put together
>   here, sum up my experience accurately.

> The Lord-of-the-Flies mansplaining exhibited by some (but not all, or
>   even most) SO participants is kind of endemic to the software
>   development profession. I’m not sure a different approach can fix it.
>
> What’s telling is that the SO answers that top the search results are
>   often closed for various reason even though they contain reasonable
>   answers — along with some BS, and various SO trolls duking it out with
>   other participants and themselves. Still, it’s useful.
>
> Personally, I tried commenting and answering on a handlful of
>   questions when I first joined and soon came to the conclusion that I
>   didn’t want to spend the time or effort to join the club.

> SO is like Wikipedia; everyone uses it every day, but agree it’s
>   completely broken.
>
> *“Nobody goes there anymore. It’s too crowded.” Yogi Berra*

> You sir deserves a cookie, oops, a medal of honor for that post. I
>   totally agree with you. S.O. is full of trolls, I was an active user
>   once trying to answer every question that I saw that I could be of
>   some help, I would also post very detailed questions, just so I might
>   avoid the duplicate or down vote thing, yet, I lost like 3 accounts
>   due to down votes and decided to stop participating. Today I only use
>   it for asking questions and I have many different accounts for that.
>   Even when I place the most detailed question, they down vote it. My
>   conclusion is that those trolls down vote questions on purpose because
>   it’s a system based on reputation, so everything they can do to harm
>   someone else’s reputation, they will do. The main problem is the down
>   vote function, it should be disabled by default and only be allowed to
>   be used by highly reputable users, or disabled for once.

If you look at those comments, however, you'll also see that the people who wrote them are mostly male and White. So I have to disagree with Jay Hanlon the notion that issue has anything to do with "women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups".

In my experience, the unfriendliness on SO is not a gender or race thing. I believe the real problem here is that programmers (on average) just happen to be rather elitist and have below average social skills. This is reflected in the way people are treated in an online community that's filled with programmers. And this affects people across gender and racial lines.

The often ambiguous or outright nonsensical rules makes things worse by encouraging people to downvote or close well-written questions that real with real life programming issues that could help many thousands of people, just because it happens to break some arbitrary rule that makes sense for only a sub-group of the questions it applies to.

While I do believe that replacing the current set of rules by more common sense rules could improve this community significantly, things can only improve if the owners and moderators of this website acknowledge that there is a problem and that their rules have something to do with it. Unfortunately, I've only encountered denial when addressing this with moderators in the past.

Comment: (1) What sort of rules changes would you propose to fix what you see as a lack of social skills? That sounds like an enormously difficult challenge to solve. (2) I've read your post before, and that view I have now of it is that the data needs analysing - some folks will have a legitimate complaint, and perhaps the community (including me) needs to get better at hearing that. Unfortunately, I also see off-site complainants who were furious that readers would not urgently help them cheat on their homework. We need to separate those two groups out, and look at the scale of them.

Comment: (3) Of course, we're not going to satisfy the aims of Be Nice if we start telling folks they're socially inept. That is akin to shaming, which is not a good example to set. ("Taste of their own medicine" is not a healthy stance, even if your commentariat might secretly support it `;-)`).

Comment: @halfer : One very bad combo of rules is to (1) not allow new users to post comments and (2) not to allow people to ask additional info in their answer. — Often, you need additional info to be able to answer a question, and not being able to post comments forces new users to ask for info in their answer. That answer then gets downvoted and deleted, resulting into a horrible first experience for someone who is just trying to help as much as he can with the tools offered to him. — Just allowing new users to post comments would fix this!

Comment: That blog post has been debunked often enough. All of those complaints are without links to actual evidence. A lot of those complaints come from users who don't know how to ask an answerable question. All those comments like _"Why do you want to do this"_ might be annoying (even though they're just as likely there to ask for missing context), but don't stand in the way of getting your question answered. And yes, you need a little investment in editing or answering before you can comment, because of spam. That's a shame, but not elitist nor rude nor unwelcoming.

Comment: Somebody actually sent me a link to that post off-site insinuating that I was part of the problem. I do appear in that screenshot there, but I have a hard time discerning what exactly was problematic about my comment there. That's the general issue I have with that post and the comments: there's a lot of bemoaning of the status quo coupled with name calling, but few concrete details and even less weighing that against SO's priorities.

Comment: @John: I'm not sure I understand your example - new users who have posted a question can comment under their own question as far as I know. Yes, if there is meta-commentary "please ask me what code you want to see", "let me know if you need anything else" etc then it gets excised, since readers are not in need of prompting to ask clarification questions. I wouldn't necessarily be opposed to letting <50 users comment on posts they had not authored, but I expect quality to go through the floor. I wonder, can I tempt you to write a new Meta proposal about this? I'd be happy to reply there.

Comment: @CodeCaster : One of the problems with SO is that many really useful programming questions simply cannot be asked. Many really useful questions are often mass downvoted and closed for being "too broad", "primarily opinion-based", asking to "recommend or find an off-site resource" or other stupid reasons. I can't count the times I've found a really good question on SO that could help me in my real life project, only to see it's been closed for some stupid reason.

Comment: @deceze : The issue with the question in that particular screenshot is that it got mass downvoted and closed instead of simply answered. His question was a totally valid question and "what you want cannot be done in JavaScript" would have been a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @halfer : New users can't comment on other people's questions. You need a minimum reputation of 50 to be able to post comments on other people's questions. And when you're new, a reputation of 50 is pretty hard to obtain. So this prevents new users from asking for the information they need to answer someone's question until they get those precious 50 reputation points, which leads to a lot of frustration and effectively discourages people from participating.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: sure, yes. The prevailing opinion is that 50 is easy to obtain - it is two or three well-written and helpful answers. Of course, the cap could be dropped to 25 or some other number, but if there is no cap at all (presumably going back to how it was when the site started) then we'll have a right mess to clean up. Not a rhetorical question: is it too much to ask users to show they want to add content of value? (Do please also make a fresh Meta proposal, so it can be properly explored).

Comment: _"I can't count the times I've found a really good question on SO that could help me"_ - yeah, that claim gets thrown around a lot, without any evidence whatsoever. Got some links? I won't deny some questions are inadvertently closed, but usually there's a really good reason to close questions. See the [scope] tag on Meta for discussions.

Comment: @halfer : 50 reputation may be easy to obtain when you already have 500+ answers and you've been here for quite a while, but it can be pretty damn hard to obtain it when you're new. Anyway, this issue has already been raised on meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250977/unable-to-comment-as-a-new-member-what-about-unclear-questions), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments), etc. If you raise it again, your question is likely to just get closed as a duplicate of one of the other questions related to this issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Take questions of the type `"What library can I use to do X?"` These are consistently closed for being `asking to "recommend or find an off-site resource"`. Yet, the best solution to many programming problems happens to be `"just use library A. You use it like this..."`. Thus, the inability to ask such questions here on SO prevents many programmers from getting the best solution to their problem... and in many cases prevents them from finding any solution at all!

Comment: @John library recommendations attract spam, get outdated almost immediately after being answered, are too specific for one use case to answer (library A doesn't support feature X, so here comes yet another question) and are simply out of scope for Stack Overflow. Just search your favorite repository such as NPM, Maven or NuGet.

Comment: @CodeCaster : SO is full of highly specific questions like `"This my CSS code. Why is my button not red?"`. These are unlikely to be useful to more than one person, yet in my experience they are rarely ever closed. Meanwhile, a reference to a high quality library can help many thousands of people for years. Sure, libraries do get outdated in time, but so do code snippets. Heck, this site is full of code snippets that are totally outdated. So why single out references to libraries?

Comment: @CodeCaster : (continued) It seems to me that anyone with even very mediocre knowledge of a programming language should be able to distinguish spammy `"use library A"` answers that are completely unrelated to the question and answers where referencing a library happens to be a good solution for the problem at hand. And, IMO, distinguishing between both and allowing only the latter would be one of many small improvements that would make SO a lot more useful than it is today!

Comment: *"The issue with the question in that particular screenshot is…"* – Yes, that is fair criticism and something we should talk about. My meta-complaint is that little of the criticism levelled against SO is that clear and actionable. Again, somebody pointed me to that link and said little more than "you're part of the problem". That tells me nothing. And I think a lot of the discussion around The Blog Post suffers from the same problem: *what exactly are we actually complaining about and rebutting?*

Comment: @deceze : IMO, there's two different problems that both result in SO feeling very unwelcoming to many : (1) rules that don't always make sense and are often counter-prodtive - (2) a community consisting of mostly people with below average social skills — We can't really do anything about the latter, but we can improve the former by carefully re-evaluating the current rules and looking for ways to improve... like allowing people to ask for libraries or allowing them to comment on questions if they have <50 reputation.

Comment: Agreed. SO is a big experiment with a large social component. The rules were set up to combat [specific problems with the status quo when SO was created](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362804/476). A decade later we should have some data on how those rules influence social behaviour in a sizeable group of people, and reevaluate what can be tweaked about those rules.

Comment: Specifically, *<50 commenting* may be desirable. We don't really know whether and how it would be abused if allowed. Needs investigation. – OTOH, we *do* have examples of library recommendation questions, and they typically become entirely counter productive after a short while, which is why they were disallowed. Instead http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com was created, where that scenario can be played out.

Comment: @deceze : The people who visit softwarerecs.stackexchange.com are but a fraction of the people visiting here. So, if I need a library to help me with a very specific problem, changes of finding an answer there is practically zero. — Anyway, I understand why this rule was applied in the first place. It seems to me this was caused because such questions ended up in intense discussions on what is the best library. However, not nearly all requests for a library encourage this behavior. So why not make a distinction here?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly you would make this distinction. And the main issue is that *over time* answers simply pile up with links to random libraries of varying quality, often promoted by their creators, and it ends up no better than a random Google search result, but partly outdated and skewed towards self-promoted stuff. Yet in SO's model such threads hang around forever and ever and ideally will be the first search result on Google. So, if you have concrete ideas how to fix that and make recommendation questions work on SO, by all means, post a specific new topic about it.

Comment: And yes, softwarerecs.SE has that problem you mention. But if they do attract a critical mass of people, they'll have SO's problem in return too. Sometimes there simply *isn't* a good solution for a problem. (Again, if you have one, post about it.)

Comment: @deceze : `And the main issue is that over time answers simply pile up with links to random libraries of varying quality, often promoted by their creators, and it ends up no better than a random Google search result, but partly outdated and skewed towards self-promoted stuff` — How is that different from the many questions where a dozen or more people post their own code snippet that is often only slightly different from the code in other answers, with many of those code snippets being wrong, incomplete or outdated? I don't see the difference, really...

Comment: A piece of code providing a solution to a clearly stated problem typically ages a lot better than a link to today's hottest framework. How to cast to an int (or whatever) in C11 will work the same today as it did 5 years ago as it will 10 years from now. And it can be tested and disproven and downvoted or promoted as correct. It is also better scoped: there are only so many ways to cast to an int, but there are often dozens or hundreds of libraries solving the same problem, and *nobody* has tried them all to be able to give an objective evaluation and pick the best one.

Comment: @deceze : Some libraries are outdated in less than a year. Other libraries get outdated very slowly and are used for decades. Take `cURL` for example. That library was first released in 1997 and it's still being used by many developers today. — For many specific use cases, there's but a handful of libraries (at best) that support it out of the box. Say, for example, that you want a JavaScript library that supports 3D maps with support of 3D meshes and point clouds. Simply being asked for it here could save someone hours or maybe days searching for a library that fits that specific use case!

Comment: I'm not denying that there's any value in such questions. I'm saying the problems, as far as we understand them so far, outweigh the benefits. And it's unclear how to distinguish the two or who decides which recommendation questions get to stay alive and which won't.

Comment: @deceze : IMO there's a big difference between asking people to recommend what is the best library to do X (which is mostly a matter of opinion) and asking people for ANY library that can do X (which is a matter of fact). Currently, SO does not distinguish between both. I believe it should make the distinction and treat both types of question differently!

Comment: That seems like only a minor semantic distinction. If OPs avoid the magic keyword "best", we keep the question? And how is that better than what Google would do for you (except slower and more manual)?

Comment: @deceze : It all depends on the use case. — Using Google, it's very hard to find a JavaScript library that supports 3D maps with support of 3D meshes and point clouds. If I could ask the experts here on SO, I could have many decent solutions in a matter of minutes!

Comment: Agreed, Google cannot find *everything* for you. That doesn't invalidate the issues I laid out above. It's something that can be discussed and perhaps a beneficial solution can be found. To circle back around to the source of this discussion though, nothing will change if we're just yelling empty accusations into the void. I found this short exchange more constructive than your entire blog post to be honest. I don't know if this particular thing can be resolved, but at least I have more of an idea what's going on.

Comment: @deceze : Let's take another use case: suppose I'm looking for library that can generically build a family tree structure in HTML or SVG where every node can have two parents and the tree can have multiple interconnections (eg. cousins marrying each other). That's an actual use case I had a few years ago, and I still haven't found a suitable library for this. This is indeed an area where Google fails... and where I expect SO to fill the blanks. However, any attempts to find any help here on SO have left me extremely disappointed, which is what motivated me to write that article back in 2015.

Comment: @JohnSlegers If you simply ask for a library to do what you require, your question will get closed. If, on the other hand, you present example data, your requirements, what you have tried, the outcomes, **and the desired solution**, you will likely get an answer - which might be a library, or something some guy dreamed up, or... This is a basic fundamental of "how to ask", is your Hackernoon article perhaps predicated on the fact that you've apparently never read the SO help center?

Comment: @IanKemp : [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207607/how-to-display-a-family-tree-structure-with-both-parents-and-multiple-interconne) is the question I'm refering to. I gave example data and I explained exactly what I was looking for. I tried to be as detailed as I possibly could. The result : the question getting multiple downvotes, getting closed and eventually getting deleted before someone even had the chance to answer that question.

Comment: That edit and last comments don't help your case. You're just slinging mud because **you** didn't get an answer to a question **you** needed an answer to, not caring for what that would mean for the site. You can't dismiss rules, which have been crafted and refined over multiple years and are seated in tons of real-life situations, as "arbitrary" and "nonsensical". Sure, the rules could be condensed, made available in an easier-to-read format and perhaps refined, but not based on hollow accusations as you're making right now. Your blog read as a rant, your posts still do.

Comment: @CodeCaster : If many questions that could help a lot of people and would be considered good questions in a normal real life professional context get downvoted and/or closed whereas many far less useful and far lesser quality questions don't up getting downvoted or closed, there's something wrong with the way the rules are designed or applied! How can you not see that?

Comment: There is no problem in narrow questions. There are various problems with opinion-based or otherwise unmaintainable questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster : Most narrow questions are so specific they're unlikely to be helpful to anyone but the person raising the question. Broad questions can often be helpful to thousands. Yet it's the broad questions that are closed. This is simply ridiculous!

Comment: I'd be a lot more willing to listen if there was an attempt made to understand what SE *is*, and how to work with it, than just yelling about what you want SE to be.  That's why your blog post just gets written off; "He doesn't understand what SE is about".  I see some attempts at constructive suggestions, but nothing about understanding why things are the way they are.

Comment: @fbueckert : I understand perfectly why things are the way they are. At some point in time, some types of questions started resulting in lots of poor quality answers. Then, rules were set in place to prevent this from happening. And while these rules do tend to prevent those bad answers from being, they also prevent a lot of good, useful questions from being raised. And it doesn't stop SO from being flooded from loads of actually poor questions with little to no effort being put into it. So I really really understand where the rules come from. I'm just arguing that they're counterproductive!

Comment: They seem to be doing a pretty good job of trying to keep quality high.  It gives people something to point to and say these are not good questions.  That seems like a pretty effective rule to me.  If you understand why things are the way they are, it, honestly, does not show at all.  All I see is someone railing at SE for not accepting a specific subset of questions that he really wants to ask.  Calling rules arbitrary shows a lack of understanding.

Comment: @fbueckert : Most questions I encounter on SO that haven't been closed are noob questions of type `"This my CSS code. Why is my button not red?"`, with the author showing little no effort in trying to solve the problem himself. That's not what I consider high quality questions, but they aren't considered a problem when they aren't breaking any rules.

Comment: When only 0.567% of people who visited your 'viral' page liked it, then it's probably not a good idea to use that as 'proof from virality'.

Comment: I also would not consider that high quality, and would downvote it.  But, if the question hasn't been asked before, it can be very helpful to future readers, as that version of CSS will not change, and now we, hopefully, have an answer that solves that problem for anyone else that needs to turn a button red.

Comment: @fbueckert : Because most of those questions are extremely specific, they're unlikely to be helpful to anyone but the person raising that question. So no, those won't be helpful to future readers. Those questions would become mere clutter. Meanwhile, questions that can be helpful to many thousands of people because they're broad enough to apply to multiple use cases are often the ones that end up getting closed... for example for being "too broad".

Comment: I fail to see how CSS is extremely specific.  CSS 3 works like CSS 3 now, and will work like CSS 3 ten years in the future.  It seems more like you trying to use a contrived example to prove your point.

Comment: @fbueckert : If someone shows a snippet of code and asks `"Why is my button not red?"` that is very specific. The answer applies to that code specifically and that code only. And even if one of its answer could be helpful to another question where the root cause of the issue is the same or similar, it would be anything but obvious due to the way `"Why is my button not red?"` was phrased.

Comment: And the question itself is pretty bad, I agree.  But it's the *answers* that matter; the answer to that question will help *anyone* who needs to turn a button red.  And duplicates are there to help with things like phrasing.  So I'm still not seeing a problem.

Comment: @fbueckert : `the answer to that question will help anyone who needs to turn a button red.` — Actually, that question is likely to only misdirect someone from finding the solution to his problem because there are thousands (if not million) of reasons why a button that is expected to be red isn't red.

Comment: Once you start moving the goalposts, then I think the discussion has gone off the rails.  I think I've done a good job of highlighting that you don't understand the reasoning behind the rules, and now, I think I'm done.

Comment: @fbueckert : Again, I do understand the rules. And I do understand where they come from. Many of the rules just don't make sense in many of the cases they're applied to. — Just because I don't agree with the rules, that doesn't mean I don't understand the reasoning behind them. It's like arguing that someone is an Atheist because he doesn't understand the reasoning behind why people believe in a God. In my experience, Atheists typically have a better understanding reasoning behind why people believe in a God than actual believers.

Comment: "The Lord-of-the-Flies mansplaining exhibited by some (but not all, or even most) SO participants is kind of endemic to the software development profession." *Actually* mansplaining is a behavior of men toward women, and there were no female characters in Lord of the Flies. In fact, the characters were boys, not men.

Comment: "I gave example data and I explained exactly what I was looking for." - **no, you didn't. Not even remotely.** You showed two images of a website that does something like what you want, and didn't explain what the input should be in order to create that output, nor did you explain any specific salient features of that output (like, for example, even the basics of the HTML structure that should be output). You asked explicitly about library recommendations, and then **didn't** try, at all, to explain what "supporting dual parent linkage or multiple connections" should actually entail.

Comment: In short: you expected Stack Overflow to work like a discussion forum, wherein people might brainstorm about how to get the result, share personal experiences with tools, "recommend" a general "approach" rather than describing a solution to a concrete problem, etc. Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. The cited question is blatantly off topic and does not help build the library we are trying to build. We don't do design work, because design is specific to individual projects.

Comment: Writing a proper version of the question would **start** with drafting: "I have some input that looks like {data formatted as a multi-line code block here}. I need to create a web page layout that looks like {image}. The boxes should presumably be represented by div tags that contain text computed from the data in such-and-such a way, and are arranged in such-and-such a way; or maybe I need to draw boxes/text/arrows with SVG graphics; or whatever." Then you would move that off to the side, analyze the problem to figure out where you are actually stuck, and write a more *specific* question.

Answer (score -30):

The [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)
 post by [Jay Hanlon](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jhanlon/) is not discussing sexism or racism, or even suggests it.

The premise of the post is:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place

And the reason given for that premise is:

> We trained users to tell other users what they’re doing wrong, but we didn’t provide new folks with the necessary guidance to do it right.

And we are given the criteria that defines the behaviour that is felt as hostile and elitist:

> Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong. They get snarky or condescending comments for not explaining what they’ve tried (that didn’t work). They get an answer… but the answerer gets scolded for “encouraging ‘low-quality’ questions.” They get downvoted, but don’t know why, or called lazy for not speaking English fluently. Or sometimes, everything actually goes well, and they get an answer! So they thank the poster… only to be told that on Stack Overflow, “please” and “thank you” are considered noise. All these experiences add up to making Stack Overflow a very unwelcoming place for far too many.

And there are a hell of a lot of examples of this out there.  Everyone on SO would have either seen or contributed to this behaviour.  It's undeniable that it exists.  It's accepted behaviour.  Users defend this behaviour.  It's not racists. It's not sexist. But it is hostile and it is elitist.  And this is exactly what the blog post is trying to address and to stop.  And I happen to wholeheartedly agree with it.

If it also reduces or stops any actual or perceived sexism or racism too, then that is the cherry on top.

Comment: And yet, he specifically mentions "women" and "people of color". That's the point of this question. If the hostile behaviour isn't sexist or racist, then the "women, people of color" part is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Thats *not* the point.

Comment: It's the point of this question; I edited my comment.

Comment: And that's what my answer is addressing.  It's addressing the fact the the premise of the article is about hostile and elitist behaviour.

Comment: Then why does it mention "women" and "people of color"? You're missing the point.

Comment: The claim of the OP is "Jay claims in the first sentence that the community is unfriendly to women and people of color."  But thats not actually true on two accounts.  1) The post actually says "Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.", and 2) its the third sentence.

Comment: Im not missing the point at all.  The premise is that "Too many people experience Stack Overflow ¹ as a hostile or elitist place".  The second part, "especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups" is just a qualifier.

Comment: 1) "hostile" implies "unfriendly", don't you think? 2) That's childish and petty. You know what he meant.

Comment: It's also not "just a qualifier", it's a very important part of the post. Why add that qualifier if it's not relevant? Jay is claiming that SO is more hostile towards women and people of color. That _must mean_ SO is sexist and racist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment.  I agree with the post's definition of "hostile and elitist".  I don't think it is childish or petty to experience that that behaviour is hostile or elitist.  I think someone is well within their right to feel that way when encountering the described behavior.  And I agree with the post that that behaviour needs to stop.  Effective moderation can occur without that behaviour.

Comment: They added that part because it must be relevant to some degree. Thinking it means it is the ONLY THING that is relevant is a mistake.  You cant conclude "That must mean SO is sexist and racist." from that.

Comment: In some respect I have to agree with @br3nt. The Jay's title is somewhat of a click-bait to me (and it worked!).

Comment: Oh my gosh br3nt. I was replying with numbers to your numbers. When I said childish and petty, I was referring to _"its the third sentence"_. _"They added that part because it must be relevant to some degree."_ Must it?? I would consider it relevant if it was a problem on SO. @Bohemian's post is questioning whether it's actually a problem given that we see no evidence of it. _"Thinking it means it is the ONLY THING that is relevant is a mistake."_ I never said it was the ONLY THING that is relevant. I don't mean to be rude, but now you're putting words in my mouth.

Comment: I'm not putting words in your mouth at all, and yes, I did misinterpret one of your comments.  To readdress that comment... "That's childish and petty"... I'm just shining a light on the fact that the OP has misinterpreted the blog, or at the very least, is misrepresting it and sensationalising it.  And ""hostile" implies "unfriendly""... Unfriendliness is related.

Comment: This community is unfriendly for people who can't research and need to be spoon-fed with information, they can be woman, man, transgender, black, brown or white - They won't feel welcome if they don't know [ask] or can't provide a [mcve]. This has nothing to do with racism/misogyny

Comment: @AlonEitan: If they don't know how to ask, *and* they refuse to accept advice on fixing their question, *and* they respond to said advice with hostility... then the resulting downvotes generally result in a question ban.... and we still welcome them to read as much of the content of this site as they like, absolutely for free.

Comment: @AlonEitan why can they not research? If they can make it to StackOverflow they can certainly make it to Google, look through a tutorial site on their chosen subject or heaven forbid read a book. None of this has to do with gender, race or culture which is what frustrates me the most. They can even asked on meta, the options are endless.

Comment: I’ll tell you what is “elitist” @br3nt. When you [actively try to help someone who had a bad experience](https://twitter.com/lankymart/status/991046236722614272?s=21) and encourage them only to be a [shot down by self promoting activist](https://twitter.com/aprilwensel/status/991047685011525632?s=21) who seems hell bent on destroying the SO community and whos [article on medium](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) likely spawned the blog post and the ensuing discussions.

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry, I completely misread the context of your comment, hence [my rant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366937/is-stack-overflow-really-racist-sexist#comment581966_366961). See how easy it is for someone to get the wrong end of the stick when reading comments.

Comment: Ahem, wrong. He is very loud about racism etc. He even recommends we all take a racism bias test and a sexism bias test. No, Jay has gone too far with his blog, accusing us of being racist, sexist and other -ists. Many others seem to believe this too.

Comment: @Bohemian found it very hard to decipher whether they where saying it has nothing to do with racism/misogyny, or whether it had everything to do with it. Still reading it and unsure how the comment was meant.

Comment: @Lankymart What my comment was meant to say is that we are NOT racist/sexist - We are trying to be professionals and we downvoting on the base of the content of the question - And NOT if that person is male/female or has a different skin color. I don't agree with that blog post at all and think it should at least be edited

Comment: Loud? There is no "racism test" at all, there is reference to a "implicit bias test" which is not about behavior but tries to get at underlying attitudes and could just as easily show bias against any group (e.g. males, whites).  Bias is not the same thing as racism. That's why the whole point of the blog is that there could be things that are unintentionally happening because we all carry around biases, including, by the way, biases against our own groups. If you have taken the test and want to have a serious discussion about it, by all means let's do that.

Comment: The blog post sucks as it is written. The meta response pretty much proves that. It is also pretty much the crux of Stack Overflow as a whole and proves the point that the blog post should have focused on making without diving into really awkward specifics - how you communicate and how you act is vitally important to defining the results you aim to get. If you do it wrong, you get poor results even with the best intentions.

Comment: I can't understand the point of confusion here. Saying "Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups." is **explicitly** saying that "women" and "people of color" **in particular** "experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place". If certain groups in particular have an experience, and the author deems it appropriate to highlight this, **that is necessarily a claim** that there is a bias towards those groups having the experience. **That is what the word "bias" means.**

Comment: It is, of course, entirely possible that a fair and equal system results in certain groups "experiencing" something disproportionately - after all, there are arbitrarily many ways to group people. However, such disproportionate experience **is not "particular" or a sign of a problem** if we are actually talking about a "fair and equal system" - **that's necessarily entailed by "fairness" and "equality"**. If people are being treated the same way, and a disparate outcome between groups results, that isn't bias created by the treatment.

Comment: It *could be* bias injected into the system from outside, for example due to pre-existing societal forces; or it could be a disproportionate result of something innocuous - for example, a statistical tendency in personal preferences. However, regardless of the cause, such a disparity is **neither the fault of the system, nor its moral responsibility to correct**. This should be obvious, but activists keep getting it wrong because it gets in the way of their axe-grinding.