# How could I improve this question? What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, downvotes

The topic of this question has been circling around in my mind for quite some time now as I work on projects.  I spent parts of three days researching and composing this question and writing code to demonstrate it.  I included links to resources and explained their relevance to the question.  I outlined the issue as succinctly as I could, which still required quite a few paragraphs due to the relative complexity of the topic, in my mind.  Yet it was immediately met with 3 downvotes and not much useful help.

Where did I go wrong, and how could I improve it?

[Long running CPU-bound synchronous implementation of an interface that returns a Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043840/long-running-cpu-bound-synchronous-implementation-of-an-interface-that-returns-a)

Comment: You did get a comment speculating on the reason for the downvotes, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, but I think the comment was off-base.  The "minimal" in [mcve] refers to code, not to the substance of the question.

Comment: On first glance: Damn, that's a wall of text. _"Ain't Nobody Got Time for That!"_

Comment: It's a wall of text...because of a complicated question, as I stated.  That's why I put a TL;DR at the top.

Comment: And maybe the down-voters are as "off-base" as that commenter. You shouldn't dismiss feedback if you are looking for down-vote reasons.

Comment: And for people who don't want to read a "wall of text", just move on.  Why the DV?

Comment: @rory.ap: Maybe because they expect an MCVE. To them, that can be a valid downvote reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus -- how much more minimal could I make my code?  It has to be complete...

Comment: The point is that the question itself should also be as concise as it can be. That's why I removed quite a bit in the edit.

Comment: When it comes to votes, reality isn't as important as perception. Whether they are right or wrong, people seeing your question could very well go "wow, this just **can't** be an MCVE" and downvote based on that. Should they read your question fully and try to understand it? in all likelihood, yes. Is your code as minimal as needed? It does look like it. Is it possible some people make mistakes? yes, entirely.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I can play the devil avocat for anything, but here I fail. I personnally won't upvote it before reading completely, and the related ressource. But for me downvote are for bad question. If I were you I will assume that a cat click the dv button.

Comment: I don't get it either.  Are those interfaces not a solved problem, thouigh?  Usually, the interface is async, a completion function/methjod/task/whatever is supplied by the user and gets called when the work is done.  If the user wants to wait in a synchronous manner, it can itself wait on its own event/semaphore/whatever and have it signaled by the completion.   I would not, myself, vote on a Java Q anyway - not enough skills;(

Comment: @rory.ap Maybe because they think a wall of text makes for a poor question. Why does anyone downvote anything instead of "just moving on"? It's called curation.

Comment: It's verbose and long and just so long-winded, it would me a long long time to get head around said question, even if I were an expert on the topic. tldr: it's wordy

Comment: @nz_21 okay I guess that's my whole point here.  How do I take such a question and boil it down so it's not verbose and long-winded?  I feel if I don't provide the right amount of information I'll get an "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad".

Comment: Now I'm looking at my question again after all these "wall of code" and "too verbose" comments, and I'm thinking....really?  You folks have too low a tolerance for pain.  It's really not *that* verbose.  Remember, verbosity means "using more words than are needed" not "is kinda long".  I feel I used enough words to explain my situation.  Just my opinion I guess.

Comment: @rory.ap I'm no expert but a few improvements I might make: 1) Bullet points describing your attempts. 2) **Bold** for stuff that's *really* important. As the question stands, I can't tell what problem you want to specifically solve, I just have a verbose overview. 3)  Related to #1, a "Here's what I tried:" and "Why that didn't work:" heading.

Comment: @nz_21 -- "As the question stands, I can't tell what problem you want to specifically solve" -- it's right there in the TL;DR at the top of the question.  "Here's what I tried:" and "Why that didn't work:" -- It's not that kind of problem.  I didn't *do* anything that didn't *work*.

Comment: It's a design question, which I guess is a clear indication that this should probably go on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23+or+design-patterns+or+object-oriented+or+.net+or+database+or+algorithms+or+coding-style+or+terminology+or+design-patterns+or+programming-practices+or+architectural-patterns+or+patterns-and-practices+or+vb.net.  Still, I don't think it's necessarily off-topic for SO.  I've seen similar questions that weren't closed and were received well.

Comment: @rory.ap Regarding your last comment - using old well-received stuff as a defense for new stuff in a similar vein is dangerous; it is possible that the similar questions you saw simply weren't closed because of a lack of attention from curators/moderating users. In the same vein as 'two wrongs don't make a right', two open questions about an off-topic subject don't make the subject on-topic (just as an example, not saying your question is off-topic). Personally though I would recommend asking it on Software Engineering instead. I think you will get a deeper, more thorough answer there.

Comment: I think your question is reasonable and I disagree with the downvotes, which look to me to be from people who didn't even read the question and just downvoted based on a quick glance at the length.  Seeing what happened here, I'll be extra careful to be concise on SO from now on.

Comment: @nz_21 Please no, bullet points or lists are regularly abused, and overusing bold doesn't make your question easier to read, it is more a distraction than helping.

Comment: It is also entirely possible people downvoted because of errors in terminology, eg _"many of them long-running CPU-bound operations (because the API blocks on the database IO)"_. Which makes it IO-bound, not CPU-bound, and therefor removes the entire premise of your question (as given in the title).

Answer (score 14):

I've avoided asking questions where I felt like I needed a white board to ask it 'live' as people read it, but that was only because I tend to predict and optimize for time. I knew I could probably make more progress with the problem in the amount of time it would take me to explain it and wait for answers. That was sometimes disappointing, because it caused me to abandon some ideas that would have become the worst legacy disasters anyone would ever inherit.

All kidding aside, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your question. I was a little surprised at the reception; two years ago it was usually just "crickets chirping" if you posted something and folks thought *sure looks interesting, but ain't nobody got time for that.* You'd see the same questions again after a bounty was placed.

I'm also not an expert when it comes to what you're talking about in the question, but the pattern seems *incredibly* strange to me, so I can see why someone *might* have said "asks a lot, and not all that useful to future visitors". My take on this is that you got so incredibly focused on capturing such a huge breadth of context to frame the problem, you forgot to put clear emphasis on the 'what' and 'why'. But that's a bit of a nitpick, your question passed *my* litmus test which is *it made me want to go digging to figure out what you're doing over there* -- even though I don't have time to do it.

I thought it was worth an up-vote, it seems like the kind of thing someone with the right kinds of war scars might passionately answer. I think you just got a little lost getting all of that aloof, but it's new to me that you'd lose the benefit of the doubt (based on research and effort presented) as to usefulness.

But, then again, If someone had a quick 20 minutes to go answer questions as a warm-up exercise, and ended up burning that while trying to parse your question a few times, I can kinda understand the reaction.

**TL;DR:** I think you need a better summary of what's currently wrong with your design, because thinking of it in the way that you explained it isn't   helping me wrap my head around it quickly. Personally, I take that as a sign that I might learn something by digging more, but I can see why others didn't realize it would burn 10 minutes until it had.

Comment: Can I just point out that I like how this has a TL;DR that's basically telling the OP to make a TL;DR?

Comment: Recursion: [everyone loves recursion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373414/how-could-i-improve-this-question-what-did-i-do-wrong/373417#comment626222_373417).

Comment: The question makes it clear that the OP *doesn't know* if anything is wrong with their design ("Is this an example where it's preferable to break the 'no async wrapper for sync code' rule?"). I don't see how they could explain "what's wrong with their design" if they're not even sure they have a problem. This makes the question open ended and subjective, without having a clear goal in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Several problems come immediately to mind.

1. There isn't a clear statement of a goal. Your question is a meandering through your own confusion about what you *should* be doing. This makes the question subjective and open ended. Being in that situation is fine, but pouring that situation out into an SO question typically makes for a poor post on this site.

   On a related but more specific note, you have this rather confusing statement in the middle of your question:

   > ...many of them long-running CPU-bound operations (because the API blocks on the database IO).

   My first reaction to this is to question if you know what you're talking about at all. Database IO is not a CPU bound operation; blocking on IO and being CPU bound are mutually exclusive (for a single operation). Perhaps this is just poorly worded, but as a reader trying to understand what you're asking, I have no idea what you're talking about there and think maybe you're confused about what those concepts mean. If you are, this is something you should have looked into and understood a bit more before posting, which would have resulted in a clearer post.
2. The underlying goal is completely design oriented. It's not about the *code* as much as it is about the *principles* of the technology you're using. This is readily apparent just looking at the end of your question:

   > Is this an example where it's preferable to break the "no async wrapper for sync code" rule?

   The answer probably won't (or at least doesn't need to) involve code. You could ask the same question about a number of other languages without even involving C#. This immediately suggests it'd probably be a much better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), where well-asked questions about design principles and norms find a home.
3. You've included far too many details.

   In an attempt to narrow it down, you've included a lot of unnecessary details (like you have a "business logic layer into which services are injected as dependencies" and a "data repository service that performs CRUD"). Your question is about an overall design. **The real design question is getting lost in this overload of details.**

   As a result of all that specificity and those code sample, your question has morphed into something approaching a "Here is my entire code base; you figure it out," question. These are *awful* to try to read through as an answerer.

   Furthermore, the enormous amount of detail has reduced the usefulness to future readers. It is *so* detailed that even if you get a good answer, future readers are going to have trouble figuring out whether the advice applies to their situation or not. It's gotten pretty close to falling into the old "too localized" close reason.

To fix it, make your question about the *principles* and the *overall design* and ask on SoftwareEngineering.SE instead. This will probably allow you to omit an enormous amount of irrelevant detail and the code samples and instead craft a question that focuses on only the specific elements of your design needed to address the issue of having an asynchronous wrapper. A TL;DR section isn't going to fix this.

Comment: I also think the confusion of the OP surfaces in describing a **CPU-bound task blocked on I/O**. By definition, it's *either* CPU-bound (meaning, the CPU is computing stuff) OR blocked on I/O, unless one uses busy-waiting... which should be made explicit if it is the case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point. I noted something about it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

One simple suggestion, and I'm not sure how much difference it would make, but I think it could be helpful:

```
Try to restructure it a bit so people can see some code earlier;
// (sorry for using a code block for non-code. It's a visual aid ;-) )
```

If people are judging it quickly as a "wall of text" and downvoting based on that without reading it much (speculation, and I haven't read it myself, to be honest), it may help to break it up if you can; some text, then some code, then some more text. As it is, on my monitor I only see the first couple of lines of code above the fold, and before the edit, I wouldn't have seen any.

I think design is important in writing Q&A, especially if you have a long, complex question like yours. Do as much as you can to make it easier for people to parse it. The more time-consuming it looks, the fewer people who will be willing to do it, and some of the ones who aren't will probably downvote it. Whether or not they should do that is subjective, but of course people are free to vote how they want to, and I assume the reasoning is something like "if I think it's too much to read, then I think it's not useful."

I'm not referring to whether it's on-topic or sufficiently MCVE'd, but assuming it is, I think just making it look less like an essay will make it more likely for people to want to engage with it.