# Why is user1114 no longer a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators

As of yesterday, [user1114](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/user1114?tab=profile) was a moderator on Stack Overflow. Today they are not. What happened?

(I am aware that nobody is obliged to answer this question, but this doesn't make it different from any other question, on meta or main. Someone *might* want to answer.)

Comment: I would rather not discuss it.

Comment: @user1114 Man, this is some heavy deja vu right here. Be good.

Comment: @user1114 Thank you for all you've done to make this a better place.

Comment: We should refer to the current situation as **Bloggate**. Seems apt.

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to mention their former name (which still can be found on comment threads, so it's not exactly secret)? I don't know and don't care about some "user1114", but I would grief for the community loosing a well-known and long-term member.

Comment: @Bergi I would think so, They want whatever has happened to remain under wraps and releasing who they are to those that don't know just encourages prying.

Comment: @Will I haven't been on SO long enough to get the reference. Why is this deja vu?

Comment: Given that the involved parties would prefer not to reveal this information, really all the rest of us could do is speculate. That being said, it seems like this really ought to be closed as "primarily opinion-based."

Comment: @StevenVascellaro To me, it seems user1114 was elected in 2015, but left a message in 2016 saying "I'm no longer a moderator". That may be the "deja vu" that Will is talking about.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Deja vu when somebody notices you're not a mod anymore https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187245/1228

Comment: @user1114 - hope you are ok, and thank you for everything. You gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: I don't even understand how this question could have been closed as *pob*. It says `answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, [...]` What ?! OP's asking for facts here.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub There's nothing further to discuss. In fact, I wouldn't mind if they history locked this post to avoid further speculation.

Comment: @Nisarg that would be a better idea than closing for the wrong reason.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I think primarily it was to remove this question from the "hot meta posts" list, see the trailing comments on Shog's answer.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub The thing is, a moderator locking this might appear as if "someone" wants to hide "something" (and fuel further speculation), so I figured they might not want to do it. The next best alternative is for the community to close it.

Comment: @Nisarg Ok. I re-read the closing reason and I couldn't agree more

Comment: Potential reopen voters: there is absolutely no reason to reopen this, so please don't.

Comment: This question is not primarily opinion-based. Low quality and inane, perhaps, but not primarily opinion-based. People don't just stop being moderators for no reason. Perhaps no one is willing to answer the question at this time - that's fine, but again not a reason to close.

Comment: There's no valid reason to close this question at all. It's about the governance of SO, it's very well interest of SO.

Comment: Dunno how much the close status matters, though if it's to be closed, it'd seem that the best close reason might be **_off-topic_**, perhaps for the reason **"_This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center._"**.  The argument'd be that this question isn't about StackOverflow, but rather the personal affairs of a particular StackOverflow user, making it off-topic.

Comment: Personally I only cared for the on-topic part, i.e. to ensure that there was nothing unethical occurring in StackExchange's governance.  The former-mod's confirmation that this was their choice strikes me as an adequate answer.

Answer (score 86):

For the moment, that's best left between me and user1114; they're free to talk about it if they wish. But as [they have indicated that they do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367206/why-is-user1114-no-longer-a-moderator#comment584277_367206) let's respect their privacy and not pry.

Comment: I think for the sake of the integrity of the so-called "democracy" here (?) it might make sense to at least indicate whether this change was something they consented to or not? It would seem the constituents have a right to know at least this bit.

Comment: @Mehrdad - As another member of this community... let's just drop it for now. Sometimes, you just need to let people explain things on their terms when the time is right.

Comment: @TravisJ: Personally, I agree. I just wanted to point out that it can raise questions about the governance structure of the site at a not-entirely-insignificant time.

Comment: @Mehrdad if it were not consensual, would anyone say it wasn't consensual? If not, then is there any point in asking?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Would anyone? Sure. Would everyone? No.

Comment: Can we at least assume that a mod wasn't stripped of their position for difference of opinion?  I mean, it looks like they left [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color/366855#comment578979_366683) shortly before their alias reverted and accounts were dissociated, which seemed a little off.

Comment: Just to add - at least for me, the incredible toxicity reflected in the blog post and then in the Meta posts was unexpected.  I'm not entirely sure what's going on behind the scenes with SE right now, though the tonality of it has been jarring.  It'd be nice to be less confused about what's caused all of this discord in what'd seemed like a stable community.

Comment: @Nat "Can we at least assume that a mod wasn't stripped of their position for difference of opinion?" -- I don't think we have much to fear with respect to that. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366937/2751851) was also posted by a mod.

Comment: There's been no account or name stripping, @nat. Anyone can hide accounts or change their name if they wish to. And while I understand this is concerning, respect for the privacy of someone who *volunteered* their time to serve the site is not too much to ask I think.

Comment: Moderators are allowed to disagree. To the extent that this site is a democracy, do not take this as evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I think it would have been better to just not post this.  It implies there could have been a conflict.  No answer would have be more respect for his privacy.

Comment: I second the people demanding to know whether the company just revoked a mod's position over their disagreement with Jay's blog post. @user1114, whether that is what happened or not, it's better for the community to know. Shog9 says you are free to discuss it; I think you should at least tell us, explicitly, whether your mod status was revoked against your will for speaking up against the company's political views. If that *is* what happened, it's a big deal for all of us, not just you, and if it's *not* what happened, it'd be responsible  to quell the speculation.

Comment: I don't understand the discussion here. Nobody has a duty to reveal anything. If they want to talk about it, fine. If they don't, as this answer says, then that's the end of it. "But may we at least know if ... ?" Nope. If you could, that would have been mentioned in the answer here.

Comment: Hey, I don't like the politics in here either. I don't do role playing, and I am not going to pretend I like bad, unresearched questions all of a sudden. But in cases like this, if someone draws a line somewhere, I'll respect it.

Comment: @duplode Before reading your comment, I was going to point to that question too as evidence of the same conclusion you drew - only I came a few hours later than you and found that it's now locked, and much of Bohemian's writing in the comments now purged. We have no way to know what conversations are now going on with Bohemian behind the scenes. It's precisely *because* we can see public action being taken against other moderators' dissents that an explicit statement one way or the other about whether the staff is punishing mods who spoke out against the blog post would be valuable right now.

Comment: @MarkAmery Probably best not to give names at the moment.

Comment: No, they weren't de-modded for disagreeing with the blog post, @Mark. If I went around stripping diamonds from every moderator with a bone to pick over that blog post, we'd be down half our moderators tomorrow.

Comment: @Shog9 I expected as much, but was worried enough to want confirmation. Good to have it. With that, I'll back off and allow user1114 his privacy.

Comment: I don't get to take politically expedient routes for some things, @paparazzo. We demand that moderators are accountable for their actions, even when all that they can say is "I can't talk about this publicly" - if I don't hold myself to that same standard, then what business do I have asking it of anyone else? I can't stop speculation; the most I can do is what I have done: request that out of respect for our comrade we rein it in.

Comment: @Shog9 Now you more imply it was because of an action.  That is not what I call rein it in.  Just my opinion.  Was not my intent to debate it with you.  I will leave this alone.

Comment: I am in full agreement with dropping it out of respect for privacy. To that end, could somebody remove this question from the Hot Questions list on the right?  It would seem counter-productive to leave it there. I don't advocate deleting, just don't have it "hot."

Comment: It seems like the question really ought to be closed as "primarily opinion-based" as well - given that the involved parties would prefer not to answer this (and are well within their rights to do so IMHO), really all the rest of us who weren't involved in the decision could possibly do is to speculate.

Comment: I totally agree with @Ajean about removing it from the "Hot Questions" list, maybe even tagging it as [status-declined] or something like that as well.

Comment: Closing should suffice

Comment: I'm slightly baffled by the reopen votes on the question - not sure why it's worth reopening or why people think that it's still a productive discussion given the circumstances.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Agreed. If it opens I'll vote to close, if that helps.

Comment: Note, 1) the hot meta post list is random, 2) it only feature post younger than 4 days, 3) tagging as status-complete would make it ineligible to be featured.