# Do people revise questions differently based on gender on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering three general questions:

- Whether people, based on gender, revise the question differently on Stackoverflow and similar Technical Q&A websites.
- How do people measure the difference between gender?
- If none of the results is precise for the question, is it possible to achieve through Stackoverflow-API?

Hope there are some academic results for this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Heavily related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366937/1233251

Answer (score 7):

Nothing about an individual gives away any hint of what their gender is, unless it's explicitly disclosed in the content they're posting or in their profile.

If it's a part of the content they're posting on Stack Overflow, then that is the *definition* of an off-topic question or an inappropriate answer.

If you want to ask how Stack Overflow qualitatively measures gender, well...*maybe* that's a better question to ask? It'd be suitable on Meta Stack Exchange, and not here.

Comment: "How Stack Overflow qualitatively measures gender" is simple: [they ask the question](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-gender).